# SqlAlchemy: Table locking with `get or create` pattern

Tags: postgresql, locking, sqlalchemy

I'm using a get_or_create pattern similar to the answer to this question:

[Does SQLAlchemy have an equivalent of Django's get_or_create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546207/)

But I'm having trouble with another thread creating an instance (with the same pk) between the 'select' and the 'insert' of the first thread.

Should the get_or_create function lock the table for the two queries?
What is the best way of implementing locking with SqlAlchemy?

I'm using postgresql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html

The only sqlalchemy locking functionality I can see is '[for update](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html?highlight=lock#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_lockmode)', which doesn't seem to be the right type of locking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I have misunderstood your reply to my answer in the other question.

What you are looking for here probably isn't locking directly, but transactions.
http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/connections.html#using-transactions

But... are you trying to prevent executing the same insert twice? In that case you would need a lock somewhere in python (or catch the duplicate key error). That is actually the only foolproof way to do it. Try to insert and get it if you get a duplicate key error.

Comment: Sorry, I posted before I saw your reply to my comment in the other question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to WoLpH, the following seems to be working for me (EdgeInfo is an elixir model):

```
from sqlalchemy import exc

session.begin_nested()
e_info = EdgeInfo(pk_attr_1=pk_attr_1, pk_attr_2=pk_attr_2)
try:
    session.commit()
except exc.IntegrityError:
    session.rollback()
    e_info = EdgeInfo.get((pk_attr_1, pk_attr_2))
```