# SQLAlchemy ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Is there an elegant way to do an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in SQLAlchemy? I mean something with a syntax similar to `inserter.insert().execute(list_of_dictionaries)` ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

## `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` post version-1.2 for MySQL

This functionality is now built into SQLAlchemy for MySQL only. somada141's answer below has the best solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48373874/319066

## `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in the SQL statement

If you want the generated SQL to actually include `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, the simplest way involves using a `@compiles` decorator.

The code (linked from a good thread on the subject [on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/p5grh/sqlalchemy_whats_the_idiomatic_way_of_writing/)) for an example can be found [on github](https://gist.github.com/1730627):

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

@compiles(Insert)
def append_string(insert, compiler, **kw):
    s = compiler.visit_insert(insert, **kw)
    if 'append_string' in insert.kwargs:
        return s + " " + insert.kwargs['append_string']
    return s


my_connection.execute(my_table.insert(append_string = 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE foo=foo'), my_values)
```

But note that in this approach, you have to manually create the append_string. You could probably change the append_string function so that it automatically changes the insert string into an insert with 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' string, but I'm not going to do that here due to laziness.

## `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` functionality within the ORM

SQLAlchemy does not provide an interface to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `MERGE` or any other similar functionality in its ORM layer. Nevertheless, it has the [`session.merge()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#merging) function that can replicate the functionality **only if the key in question is a primary key**.

`session.merge(ModelObject)` first checks if a row with the same primary key value exists by sending a `SELECT` query (or by looking it up locally). If it does, it sets a flag somewhere indicating that ModelObject is in the database already, and that SQLAlchemy should use an `UPDATE` query. Note that merge is quite a bit more complicated than this, but it replicates the functionality well with primary keys.

But what if you want `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` functionality with a non-primary key (for example, another unique key)? Unfortunately, SQLAlchemy doesn't have any such function. Instead, you have to create something that resembles Django's `get_or_create()`. [Another StackOverflow answer covers it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587041/319066), and I'll just paste a modified, working version of it here for convenience.

```py
def get_or_create(session, model, defaults=None, **kwargs):
    instance = session.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
    if instance:
        return instance
    else:
        params = dict((k, v) for k, v in kwargs.iteritems() if not isinstance(v, ClauseElement))
        if defaults:
            params.update(defaults)
        instance = model(**params)
        return instance
```

Comment: Note that the `append_string` code is non-functional on postgres (with it's new `ON CONFLICT [IGNORE|UPDATE]` feature in 9.5, as the ORM automatically appends a `RETURNING {primary key}` to inserts, and that results in invalid SQL.

Comment: what is the `foo=foo` part doing here, and what would I replace `foo` with in my own table?

Comment: `append_string` not work get `SAWarning: Can't validate argument 'append_string'; can't locate any SQLAlchemy dialect named 'append'
  % (k, dialect_name)`

Comment: Note that the get_or_create example is exposed to race conditions on concurrent systems. Instead you should try to insert first, catch an exception on key duplication and query the result.

Answer (score 37):

I should mention that ever since the v1.2 release, the SQLAlchemy 'core' has a solution to the above with that's built in and can be seen under [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert) (copied snippet below):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert

insert_stmt = insert(my_table).values(
    id='some_existing_id',
    data='inserted value')

on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(
    data=insert_stmt.inserted.data,
    status='U'
)

conn.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
```

Comment: Seems It only for MySQL, look the link to doc.

Comment: yeah I should've clarified. The above only works for MySQL *but* Postgres for example has had such functionality for some time now with http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert.on_conflict_do_update and http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert.on_conflict_do_nothing

Comment: This also works for arrays of values, if anyone ever needs that functionality. That means that `values` also accepts `list`s of `dict` objects.

Comment: May you please give a solid example of how `data` is populated? Is it like `data={'field_1'='value1'}`. Thanks

Comment: @Houman yeah that's how you define the values and then you use `mysql_noop_upsert_columns=[OrmClass.column]` to define the update columns.

Comment: does this works for bulk upserst too? because I have not managed to get it to work

Comment: @Kailegh the above example is an UPSERT (since it INSERTs and UPDATEs on a dupe). Did you mean something else?

Comment: yeah, I mean does this work on a list of rows at the same time? o should I do it one by one? using in values an array of dicts, I have not found it in their documentation

Comment: @Kailegh yes it does. The `values` argument can be a `list` of `dict` with the field names you want inserted and then you can use the `mysql_upsert_columns` argument to define which columns to be upserted in the event of a dupe. SQLAlchemy will then compile the appropriate query to only update the right columns on the dupes

Comment: I have a unique index and an id primary key which is auto-increment.? In my case the id is keep incinerating how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @somada141 I couldn't get it working with a list of dict. 

I assume that you'd pass the list of dict to insert statement first. What would be the required arguments to `on_duplicate_key_update` in this case?

Comment: @atuljangra Did you manage to get `on_duplicate_key_update` working with a list of dict?

Comment: @somada141 please explain your comment about `mysql_upsert_columns` which is not in your answer. Same for `mysql_noop_upsert_columns`. Thx in adv

Answer (score 2):

Based on [phsource's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10561643/2297433), and for the specific use-case of using **MySQL** and completely overriding the data for the same key without performing a `DELETE` statement, one can use the following `@compiles` decorated insert expression:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

@compiles(Insert)
def append_string(insert, compiler, **kw):
    s = compiler.visit_insert(insert, **kw)
    if insert.kwargs.get('on_duplicate_key_update'):
        fields = s[s.find("(") + 1:s.find(")")].replace(" ", "").split(",")
        generated_directive = ["{0}=VALUES({0})".format(field) for field in fields]
        return s + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " + ",".join(generated_directive)
    return s
```

Comment: This example doesn't escape the field values very well. You should probably use the built-in escape methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25107658/319066

Comment: @phsource notice that in this example we override fields with their values from the original `INSERT` (referring to the field names and not the values), so no escaping is needed. Obviously, using the now-part-of-the-ORM functionality is better (unless using it with `INSERT FROM SELECT` which does not work as expected)

Answer (score 2):

My way

```py
import typing
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql

class MyRepository:

    def model(self):
        return MySqlAlchemyModel

    def upsert(self, data: typing.List[typing.Dict]):
        if not data:
            return
        model = self.model()
        if hasattr(model, 'created_at'):
            for item in data:
                item['created_at'] = datetime.now()

        stmt = mysql.insert(getattr(model, '__table__')).values(data)
        for_update = []
        for k, v in data[0].items():
            for_update.append(k)

        dup = {k: getattr(stmt.inserted, k) for k in for_update}
        stmt = stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(**dup)
        self.db.session.execute(stmt)
        self.db.session.commit()
```

Usage:

```py
myrepo.upsert([
    {
        "field11": "value11",
        "field21": "value21",
        "field31": "value31",
    },
    {
        "field12": "value12",
        "field22": "value22",
        "field32": "value32",
    },
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Got a simpler solution:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

@compiles(Insert)
def replace_string(insert, compiler, **kw):
    s = compiler.visit_insert(insert, **kw)
    s = s.replace("INSERT INTO", "REPLACE INTO")
    return s

my_connection.execute(my_table.insert(replace_string=""), my_values)
```

Comment: Take care. `REPLACE INTO` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` do different things.

Comment: Notably, it *deletes* the row, so this solution is usually terribly useless on `InnoDB` (or any other transactional engine) tables, as it chokes on most any `FOREIGN KEY` constraint

Comment: It works fine with MySql. Having said that, I do not have any foreign keys on that table.

Answer (score 1):

It's depends upon you. If you want to replace then pass `OR REPLACE` in prefixes

```
  def bulk_insert(self,objects,table):
    #table: Your table class and objects are list of dictionary [{col1:val1, col2:vale}] 
    for counter,row in enumerate(objects):
        inserter = table.__table__.insert(prefixes=['OR IGNORE'], values=row)
        try:
            self.db.execute(inserter)
        except Exception as E:
            print E
        if counter % 100 == 0:
            self.db.commit()                    
    self.db.commit()
```

Here commit interval can be changed to speed up or speed down

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have this covered but figured I'd reference another good example for mysql I found in [this](https://gist.github.com/vanpelt/1568296c0d6c97a4472ce1fcde73fc6c) gist. This also includes the use of `LAST_INSERT_ID`, which may be useful depending on your innodb auto increment settings and whether your table has a unique key. Lifting the code here for easy reference but please give the author a star if you find it useful.

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert

def upsert(model, insert_dict):
    """model can be a db.Model or a table(), insert_dict should contain a primary or unique key."""
    inserted = insert(model).values(**insert_dict)
    upserted = inserted.on_duplicate_key_update(
        id=func.LAST_INSERT_ID(model.id), **{k: inserted.inserted[k]
                               for k, v in insert_dict.items()})
    res = db.engine.execute(upserted)
    return res.lastrowid
```

Answer (score 1):

**ORM**
use `upset` func based on `on_duplicate_key_update`

```py
class Model():
    __input_data__ = dict()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.__input_data__ = kwargs
        self.session = Session(engine)

    def save(self):
        self.session.add(self)
        self.session.commit()
    
    def upsert(self, *, ingore_keys = []):
        column_keys = self.__table__.columns.keys()

        udpate_data = dict()
        for key in self.__input_data__.keys():
            if key not in column_keys:
                continue
            else:
                udpate_data[key] = self.__input_data__[key]

        insert_stmt = insert(self.__table__).values(**udpate_data)

        all_ignore_keys = ['id']
        if isinstance(ingore_keys, list):
            all_ignore_keys =[*all_ignore_keys, *ingore_keys]
        else:
            all_ignore_keys.append(ingore_keys)

        udpate_columns = dict()
        for key in self.__input_data__.keys():
            if key not in column_keys or key in all_ignore_keys:
                continue
            else:
                udpate_columns[key] = insert_stmt.inserted[key]
        
        on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(
            **udpate_columns
        )
        # self.session.add(self)
        self.session.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
        self.session.commit()
```

```py
class ManagerAssoc(ORM_Base, Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.id = idWorker.get_id()
        column_keys = self.__table__.columns.keys()
        udpate_data = dict()
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            if key not in column_keys:
                continue
            else:
                udpate_data[key] = kwargs[key]
        ORM_Base.__init__(self, **udpate_data)
        Model.__init__(self, **kwargs, id = self.id)

   ....
# you can call it as following:
manager_assoc.upsert()
manager.upsert(ingore_keys = ['manager_id'])
```

Comment: apologies if this is excessively picky, maybe you'd like to correct `udpate` to `update`?

Answer (score 1):

Update Feb 2023: SQLAlchemy version 2 was recently released and supports `on_duplicate_key_update` in the MySQL dialect. Many many thanks to Federico Caselli of the SQLAlchemy project who helped me develop sample code in a discussion at https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9328

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538576/1630244

If it's ok to post the same answer twice (?) here is my small self-contained code example:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
import sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql as mysql
from sqlalchemy import delete, select, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))


engine = db.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://USER-NAME-HERE:PASS-WORD-HERE@localhost/SCHEMA-NAME-HERE')
conn = engine.connect()

# setup step 0 - ensure the table exists
Base().metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

# setup step 1 - clean out rows with id 1..5
del_stmt = delete(User).where(User.id.in_([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
conn.execute(del_stmt)
conn.commit()
sel_stmt = select(User)
users = list(conn.execute(sel_stmt))
print(f'Table size after cleanout: {len(users)}')

# setup step 2 - insert 4 rows
ins_stmt = mysql.insert(User).values(
    [
        {"id": 1, "name": "x"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "y"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "w"},
        {"id": 4, "name": "z"},
    ]
)
conn.execute(ins_stmt)
conn.commit()
users = list(conn.execute(sel_stmt))
print(f'Table size after insert: {len(users)}')

# demonstrate upsert
ups_stmt = mysql.insert(User).values(
    [
        {"id": 1, "name": "xx"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "yy"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "ww"},
        {"id": 5, "name": "new"},
    ]
)
ups_stmt = ups_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(name=ups_stmt.inserted.name)
# if you want to see the compiled result
# x = ups_stmt.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect())
# print(x.string, x.construct_params())
conn.execute(ups_stmt)
conn.commit()

users = list(conn.execute(sel_stmt))
print(f'Table size after upsert: {len(users)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used plain sql as:

```
insert_stmt = "REPLACE INTO tablename (column1, column2) VALUES (:column_1_bind, :columnn_2_bind) "
session.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```

Answer (score -1):

As none of these solutions seem all the elegant. A brute force way is to query to see if the row exists. If it does delete the row and then insert otherwise just insert. Obviously some overhead involved but it does not rely on modifying the raw sql and it works on non orm stuff.

Comment: You know, you can go to DBA-Hell for this.

Comment: @strangeqargo As someone new to database management I'd love to know more about why that's such a bad idea.

Comment: @Nick to "check if row exists" means you can 
1) start transaction, try to find a row, end transaction. That's slow. 
2) you can forget to wrap a transaction, that's prone to errors (a row you search for might appear while you're searching)

the best  way is to use database-provided mechanisms  - on duplicate key update (IF you have a correct key structure).