# sqlalchemy literal text added to an insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, on-duplicate-key

I'm trying to get sqlalchemy to accept some more complex behavior on an insert, and can't figure out the idiomatic way to do it.  To simplify things, I was just trying to add a literal string to the end of the query, but can't find a valid way to do it.  I've seen the **"text()"** function use to add string literals to queries, but it wouldn't work the way I am using it. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do (this won't compile, but captures the idea at least...)

```
from sqlalchemy import *

metadata = MetaData()

user = Table('user', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column('likes', Integer, nullable = False),
    Column('last_liked', TIMESTAMP, nullable = False),
)

userid = 1
newlikes = 5

user.insert().values(user_id=userid, likes=newlikes) + 
    text("ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_liked=NOW(), likes = likes + " + newlikes)
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: actually, this looks helpful...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611563/sqlalchemy-on-duplicate-key-update