# Postgresql ON CONFLICT in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've read quite a few resources (ao. [1](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3529/support-postgres-95-on-conflict-upserts), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)) but I'm unable to get Postgresql's ON CONFLICT IGNORE behaviour working in sqlalchemy.

I've used [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611563/sqlalchemy-on-duplicate-key-update) as a basis, but it gives

```
SAWarning: Can't validate argument 'append_string'; can't locate any SQLAlchemy dialect named 'append'
```

I've tried adding the postgresql dialect to the @compile clause, renaming my object, but it doesn't work.
I also tried to use the `str(insert())+ " ON CONFILCT IGNORE"` without results. (not surprising btw)

How can I get the `On CONFLICT IGNORE` to get added to my inserts? I like the proposed solution, as I can see myself not wanting the `IGNORE` behaviour on each `INSERT`

ps. using python 2.7 (don't mind upgrading to 3.4/3.5), latest sqlalchemy (1.x)

Comment: You should provide example code because if this accepted answer you mention works for you (have you tested it? test it!) changing UPDATE to IGNORE should also work or you have a typo. But if code you mention also doesn't work, you might have other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this, use exists condition to prevent inserting duplicates.

for example:

```
INSERT INTO table (unique_name) 
SELECT 'some_string'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE unique_name = 'some_string')
```

you can also

```
INSERT INTO table (unique_name)
VALUES('some_string')
ON CONFLICT (unique_name) DO NOTHING
```

but if you need [insert](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) or update in single query, then this is example for you:

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname)
VALUES (5, 'Gizmo Transglobal'), (6, 'Associated Computing, Inc')
ON CONFLICT (did) DO UPDATE SET dname = EXCLUDED.dname;
```

This is an example from PostgreSQL Documentation.

Comment: Sample code, please? How does one use the exists condition to insert or update in a single statement?

Comment: Missed the vote. Fixed. Can't mark it as the correct answer though as I didn't ask the question.

Comment: I asked the question, but I still do not comprehend how this works in `sqlalchemy`

Comment: Are you asking: how to use SQL in sqlalchemy? If yes, read [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#insert-expressions). If no post your code, because I don' t know how your code works.

Comment: I would use this using Textual SQL, I presume?

Answer (score 24):

#### Using Postgres 9.6.1, sqlachemy 1.1.4, and psycopg2 2.6.2:

1. Convert your data structure to a dictionary.  From Pandas it is

   ```
   import pandas
   from sqlalchemy import MetaData
   from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
   import psycopg2

   # The dictionary should include all the values including index values
   insrt_vals = df.to_dict(orient='records')
   ```
2. Connect to database through sqlalchemy . Instead try psycog2 driver underneath and the native COPY function, which bypasses all the postgres indexing.

   ```
   csv_data = os.path.realpath('test.csv')
   con = psycopg2.connect(database = 'db01', user = 'postgres')
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute("\copy stamm_data from '%s' DELIMITER ';' csv header" % csv_data)
   con.commit()
   ```
3. Execute

   ```
   results = engine.execute(do_nothing_stmt)
   # Get number of rows inserted
   rowcount = results.rowcount
   ```

#### Warning:

This method does not work with `NaT`s out of the box.

#### Everything together

```
tst_df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['a','b','c','a','z', 'q'],
              'colB': pd.date_range(end=datetime.datetime.now() , periods=6),
              'colC' : ['a1','b2','c3','a4','z5', 'q6']})


insrt_vals = tst_df.to_dict(orient='records')
engine =      sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql://user:password@localhost/postgres")
connect = engine.connect()
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
table = meta.tables['tstbl']
insrt_stmnt = insert(table).values(insrt_vals)

do_nothing_stmt  = insrt_stmnt.on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=['colA','colB'])
results = engine.execute(do_nothing_stmt)
```

Instead of step 2 and 3 , using `psycog2` driver with the copy command in postgres is faster for larger files (approaching a gig) because it sets all the table indexing off.

```
csv_data = os.path.realpath('test.csv')
```

Answer (score 12):

This works with Postgresql 10.5 and Sqlalchemy 1.3.6:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert


table_info = {
'tableTime': '',
'deploymentID': '',
'tableData': ''
}
insert_table = insert(Table).values(table_info)
insert_table_sql = insert_table.on_conflict_do_nothing(
  index_elements=['tableTime', 'deploymentID']
)
db.session.execute(insert_table_sql)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: This should be accepted as a right answer

Answer (score 7):

This works with Postgresql 9.5:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

@compiles(Insert)
def prefix_inserts(insert, compiler, **kw):
    return compiler.visit_insert(insert, **kw) + " ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
```

I use it for `bulk_insert_mappings`. It does however not make `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` optional

Comment: Note: I added a version using a context manager to make this optional here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62305344/315936

Comment: This fails if the original insert already contains 'on conflict..' and/or 'returning' clauses (

Answer (score 4):

This is an extension of Niklas' answer.

Basically, uses a thread local state and a context manager to make appending the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` optional. It's still a big hack though.

It also only hooks the postgres specific statement, and doesn't construct the sql query manually from text.

```py
import threading
from contextlib import contextmanager

from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml import OnConflictDoNothing

state = threading.local()

@contextmanager
def on_conflict_do_nothing():
  state.active = True
  yield
  del state.active

@compiles(Insert, 'postgresql')
def prefix_inserts(insert, compiler, **kw):
  if getattr(state, "active", False):
    insert._post_values_clause = OnConflictDoNothing()
  return compiler.visit_insert(insert, **kw)
```

Comment: How to change it so that it handles cases with the existing "on conflict" clause gracefully?