# Example of using the 'callable' method in pandas.to_sql()?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I'm trying to make a specific insert statement that has an `ON CONFLICT` argument (I'm uploading to a Postgres database); will the df.to_sql(method='callable') allow that? Or is it intended for another purpose? I've read through the documentation, but I wasn't able to grasp the concept. I looked around on this website and others for similar questions, but I haven't found one yet. If possible I would love to see an example of how to use the 'callable' method in practice. Any other ideas on how to effectively load large numbers of rows from pandas using `ON CONFLICT` logic would be much appreciated as well. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Good question, not sure if you already found [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#insertion-method), but this might help.

Comment: Hey @Efran! I had seen that, but I was confused by it. I see that they've created a function that uses a cursor, but I didn't see how they actually use that function inside of pandas? I'm sure the answer I need is in that example, but it hasn't clicked for me yet. :(

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example on how to use postgres's `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` with `to_sql`

```
# import postgres specific insert
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

def to_sql_on_conflict_do_nothing(pd_table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    # This is very similar to the default to_sql function in pandas
    # Only the conn.execute line is changed
    data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
    conn.execute(insert(pd_table.table).on_conflict_do_nothing(), data)

conn = engine.connect()
df.to_sql("some_table", conn, if_exists="append", index=False, method=to_sql_on_conflict_do_nothing)
```

Comment: For anyone else interested in referencing the default to_sql function in pandas, here's the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8cb7cfe326219b83ccc8a0d0b211fab40f4575c1/pandas/io/sql.py#L853)

Answer (score 0):

I have just had similar problem, and followed by to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41238182/9669397) I came up with solution on how to send `df` to `potgresSQL` `ON CONFLICT`:

1. Send some initial data to the database to create the table

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

df.to_sql(table_name,engine)
```

2. add `primary key`

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

3. prepare index on the column (or columns) you want to check the uniqueness

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX review_id ON test(review_id);
```

4. map the sql table with `sqlalchemy`

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
ABase = automap_base()

Table = ABase.classes.table_name
Table.__tablename__ = 'table_name'
```

6. do your `insert on conflict` with:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

insrt_vals = df.to_dict(orient='records')
insrt_stmnt = insert(Table).values(insrt_vals)

do_nothing_stmt  = insrt_stmnt.on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=['review_id'])
results = engine.execute(do_nothing_stmt)
```