# REPLACE rows in mysql database table with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, replace

Python Version - 2.7.6

Pandas Version - 0.17.1

MySQLdb Version - 1.2.5

In my database ( `PRODUCT` ) , I have a table ( `XML_FEED` ). The table XML_FEED is huge ( Millions of record )
I have a pandas.DataFrame() ( `PROCESSED_DF` ). The dataframe has thousands of rows.

Now I need to run this

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE PRODUCT.XML_FEED
(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5),
VALUES (PROCESSED_DF.values)
```

Question:-

Is there a way to run `REPLACE INTO TABLE` in pandas? I already checked `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()` but that is not what I need. I do not prefer to read `XML_FEED` table in pandas because it very huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till this version `(0.17.1)` I am unable find any direct way to do this in pandas. I reported a feature request for the same.
I did this in my project with executing some queries using `MySQLdb` and then using `DataFrame.to_sql(if_exists='append')`

Suppose

1) product_id is my primary key in table PRODUCT

2) feed_id is my primary key in table XML_FEED.

SIMPLE VERSION

```
import MySQLdb
import sqlalchemy
import pandas

con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','my_password', 'database_name')
con_str = 'mysql+mysqldb://root:my_password@localhost/database_name'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(con_str) #because I am using mysql
df = pandas.read_sql('SELECT * from PRODUCT', con=engine)
df_product_id = df['product_id']
product_id_str = (str(list(df_product_id.values))).strip('[]')
delete_str = 'DELETE FROM XML_FEED WHERE feed_id IN ({0})'.format(product_id_str)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(delete_str)
con.commit()
df.to_sql('XML_FEED', if_exists='append', con=engine)# you can use flavor='mysql' if you do not want to create sqlalchemy engine but it is depreciated
```

Please note:- 
The `REPLACE [INTO]` syntax allows us to `INSERT` a row into a table, except that if a `UNIQUE KEY` (including `PRIMARY KEY`) violation occurs, the old row is deleted prior to the new INSERT, hence no violation.

Answer (score 18):

With the release of pandas 0.24.0, there is now an [official way](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-sql-method) to achieve this by passing a custom insert method to the `to_sql` function.

I was able to achieve the behavior of `REPLACE INTO` by passing this callable to `to_sql`:

```py
def mysql_replace_into(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert
    from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

    @compiles(Insert)
    def replace_string(insert, compiler, **kw):
        s = compiler.visit_insert(insert, **kw)
        s = s.replace("INSERT INTO", "REPLACE INTO")
        return s

    data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]

    conn.execute(table.table.insert(replace_string=""), data)
```

You would pass it like so:

```py
df.to_sql(db, if_exists='append', method=mysql_replace_into)
```

Alternatively, if you want the behavior of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` instead, you can use this:

```py
def mysql_replace_into(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert

    data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]

    stmt = insert(table.table).values(data)
    update_stmt = stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(**dict(zip(stmt.inserted.keys(), 
                                               stmt.inserted.values())))

    conn.execute(update_stmt)
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762400/1919794 for the compile method.

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly how I want. Just wish pandas could add a some option for this as well...

Comment: Thanks devull. This solution used to work for me just fine, except when I updated my system and installed the latest Python, Pandas, SQLAlchemy, etc. Now, I get the following error: TypeError: TableClause.insert() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_string

Answer (score 2):

I needed a generic solution to this problem, so I built on shiva's answer--maybe it will be helpful to others. This is useful in situations where you grab a table from a MySQL database (whole or filtered), update/add some rows, and want to perform a `REPLACE INTO` statement with `df.to_sql()`.

It finds the table's primary keys, performs a delete statement on the MySQL table with all keys from the pandas dataframe, and then inserts the dataframe into the MySQL table.

```
def to_sql_update(df, engine, schema, table):
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    sql = ''' SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns
              WHERE table_schema = '{schema}' AND table_name = '{table}' AND
                    COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI';
          '''.format(schema=schema, table=table)
    id_cols = [x[0] for x in engine.execute(sql).fetchall()]
    id_vals = [df[col_name].tolist() for col_name in id_cols]
    sql = ''' DELETE FROM {schema}.{table} WHERE 0 '''.format(schema=schema, table=table)
    for row in zip(*id_vals):
        sql_row = ' AND '.join([''' {}='{}' '''.format(n, v) for n, v in zip(id_cols, row)])
        sql += ' OR ({}) '.format(sql_row)
    engine.execute(sql)
    
    df.to_sql(table, engine, schema=schema, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: This works great, thank you.  However I removed line 2 because I don't think it's required, and with it you are left with an extra column 'index' which will of course cause an error - unless you meant to add df.drop(['index'], axis=1, inplace=True).

Comment: That's a good point; the second line is only needed if the df has an index set on one or more columns.

Comment: I am not able to understand about name variable ? can you help me .
 df.to_sql(name, engine, schema=schema, if_exists='append', index=False)

Comment: That was a typo, it should be `df.to_sql(table, engine ...)`. I fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score -6):

If you use to_sql you should be able to define it so that you replace values if they exist, so for a table named 'mydb' and a dataframe named 'df', you'd use:

```
df.to_sql(mydb,if_exists='replace')
```

That should replace values if they already exist, but I am not 100% sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: if_exist works for table not for rows in table.                                  if_exists : {‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’
fail: If table exists, do nothing.
replace: If table exists, drop it, recreate it, and insert data.
append: If table exists, insert data. Create if does not exist

Comment: His answer is still valid as long as it is mentioned that it replace with the whole dataframe. If his command is preceded by a filter on the df then it is an appropriate one.