# pandas.to_sql replace old data with new data based on 'unique id'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe, that I have put into sql with the below code.

**code**

```
df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(r))
pandas.DataFrame.to_sql(df, name='Database count details', con=engine)
```

**Sample data**

```
UNIQUE id   name          refreshed_at    values
2449205     ABC           2014-01-10      22
26019260    DEF           2016-03-04      51
26019261    GHI (1333)    2016-03-04      0.55
```

My intentions are to run a code once a week and to replace the data in the `.db`file with that week's data if the `unique id` matches. If it doesn't match, it will append to the `.db` file.

How should I do this? Or is there a better way to perform this task?

Comment: Here is a possible solution. [REPLACE rows in mysql database table with pandas DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34802840/848930)

Comment: There isn't any feature in sqlalchemy or pandas that can do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a feature to get through this easily. Currently, I just drop the entire table, and recreate a new one..

```
meta = MetaData()
table_to_drop = Table('Database count details', 
                       meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
table_to_drop.drop(engine)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just delete the conflicting rows before you run `to_sql`. Here is how I update results of an experiment.

```py
from sqlalchemy import select, delete, Table, MetaData
metadata = MetaData(engine)

experiment_name = 'base-20180608'
pipeline_proposals = Table('pipeline_proposals', metadata, autoload=True)
pipeline_proposals.delete().where(pipeline_proposals.c.experiment_name == experiment_name).execute()

proposals["experiment_name"]=experiment_name
proposals.to_sql("pipeline_proposals", con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: probably should do both steps within a single session

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///" + path)
#Read new data, set index:
df_new = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(r))
df_new = df_new.set_index('indexName', drop=True)
#read old data, set index:
df_old = pandas.read_sql('table', engine)
df_old = df_old .set_index('indexName', drop=True)
#Combine with old comes first
df = pandas.concat([df_old, df_new ], copy=False)
#drop duplicate, keep last which is from df_new
df = df [~df .index.duplicated(keep='last')]
#replace old table with new one
df.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists="replace")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to use "replace" instead of "insert" in mysql, ref to the method param in to_sql, we can implement it by below code (you can just change the insert_to_replace method on your need):

```
def insert_to_replace(table,con,key,data):
    for x in data:
         con.execute("replace into %s values %s " % (table.name,x,))
 
df.to_sql("targe_table_name",db.engine,index=False,if_exists='append',method=insert_to_replace)
```

Answer (score -4):

pandas.DataFrame.to_sql(df, name='Database count details', con=engine, if_exists='replace')

See the if_exists parameter for to_sql at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Attention here: if_exists refers to TABLES, not to single rows. 
If the table exists, it recreates the whole table.