# SQLAlchemy Core - INSERT IGNORE and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy Core with a MySQL database but am having a hard time finding a solution for INSERT IGNORE / DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. I hate to write a one-off query manually in the code if there's a way to handle this. Most solutions or discussions I've found center around the ORM, but not the core. And even some of those are dead links. Is it even possible?

Comment: Very much related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611563/sqlalchemy-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 20):

I know it is a bit late.. but if someone is still looking for solutions.

**FOR: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

```
ins = insert(/* table_name*/ ).values(/*your values(with PK)*/)
do_update_stmt = ins.on_duplicate_key_update(/*your values(with out PK)*/)
connection.execute(do_update_stmt)
```

[On duplicate key update docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_12.html#support-for-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

> The ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause of INSERT supported by MySQL is now supported using a **MySQL-specific** version of the Insert object

This wont be avaliable with `sqlalchemy.insert()`.

**FOR: INSERT IGNORE**

This is a bit hacky but works just fine.

```
 ins_address_stmt = insert(/* table_name*/ ).values(/*your values*/). \
            prefix_with('IGNORE')
```

[Insert prefix_with](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.HasPrefixes.prefix_with)

MySQL will suppress the error for duplicate primary key and gives a warning.

Comment: Do you know what data does (values) receive? I’ve tried with a list of class instances (just like I would with add_all() but it doesn’t work...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... `values()` takes in values to be inserted as arguments. Argument name should match tables columns. 

For e.g. `insert(customers).values(name=name, phone=phone,is_approved=is_approved)`

And Table's structure is `Table ('customers', metadata, Column('name'), Column('phone'), Column('is_approved')`

Comment: Thanks, I tried inserting the class’ instances but it ends up trying to insert the SQLAlchemy object itself, instead of the values. I chose to partially commit my code to the DB in order to avoid the eventual integrity error. I might try to drill down on the object and insert the values.

Answer (score 10):

shaktimaan's answer works great for MySQL INSERT IGNORE. If you found this page looking for SQLite INSERT IGNORE, remember to do INSERT OR IGNORE

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

```
stmt = insert(/* table_name*/ ).values(/*your values*/).prefix_with('OR IGNORE')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is:

```
stmt = YourModel.__table__.insert().prefix_with(" ignore").values(data)
session.execute(stmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Mode

```py
print '--------- test upsert --------------'
for r in rows:
    r['value'] = r['id'] + 1

sql = '''
    INSERT INTO test (id, value)
    VALUES (:id, :value)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)
'''
start = time.time()
engine.execute(text(sql), rows)
```