# Sqlalchemy add_all() ignore duplicate key IntegrityError

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm adding a list of objects `entries` to a database. Sometimes it may happen that one of this objects is already in the database (I do not have any control on that).
With only one `IntegrityError` all the transactions will fail, i.e. all the objects in `entries` will not be inserted into the database.

```
try:
    session.add_all(entries)
    session.commit()
except:
    logger.error(f"Error! Rolling back")
    session.rollback()
    raise
finally:
    session.close()
```

My desired behavior would be: if there is a `IntegrityError` in one of the `entries`, catch it and do not add that object to the database, otherwise continue normally (do not fail)

Edit: I'm usign MySQL as backend.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I depends on what backend you're using.

**PostgreSQL** has a wonderful `INSERT() ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` clause which you can use with SQLAlchemy:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
session.execute(insert(MyTable)
                .values(my_entries)
                .on_conflict_do_nothing())
```

**MySQL** has the similar `INSERT IGNORE` clause, but SQLAlchemy has less support for it. Luckily, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50870348/5015356), there is a workaround, using [`prefix_with`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.HasPrefixes.prefix_with):

```py
session.execute(MyTable.__table__
                .insert()
                .prefix_with('IGNORE')
                .values(my_entries))
```

The only thing is that `my_entries` needs to be a list of column to value mappings. That means `[{ 'id': 1, 'name': 'Ringo' }, { 'id': 2, 'name': 'Paul' }, ...]` et cetera.

Answer (score -1):

A solution I have found is to query the database before adding it

```
try:
    instance = session.query(InstancesTable).filter_by(id=entry.id).first()
    if instance:
        return
    session.add(entry)
    session.commit()
except:
    logger.error(f"Error! Rolling back")
    session.rollback()
    raise
```