# On Duplicate Update in sqlachemy fastApi

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm using fastapi with sqlalchemy, This is my code for inserting new record

```
def insert_price(db: Session, price_list: schemas.PriceList):
    db_price = models.PriceList(**price_list.dict())
    db.add(db_price)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_price)
    return db_price
```

i have a unique column and i want to update on duplicate how can i handle that?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611563/sqlalchemy-on-duplicate-key-update ? (in particular the newer answers shed some light on recent changes)