# SQLAlchemy: get Model from table name. This may imply appending some function to a metaclass constructor as far as I can see

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I want to make a function that, given the name of a table, returns the model with that **tablename**.
Eg:

```
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    ...a bunch of Columns

def getModelFromTableName(tablename):
   ...something magical
```

so getModelFromTableName('table') should return the Model class.

My aim is to use the function in a simple form generator I'm making since FormAlchemy does not work with python3.2 and I want it to handle foreign keys nicely.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to get getModelFromTableName to work?

Here's one idea I have (it might be totally wrong, I haven't worked with meta classes before...)

What if I were to make my Model classes inherit from Base as well as some other class (TableReg) and have the class meta of TableReg store Model.**tablename** in some global dictionary or Singleton.

I realise this could be totally off because Base's metaclass does some very important and totally nifty stuff that I don't want to break, but I assume there has to be a way for me to append a little bit of constructor code to the meta class of my models. Or I don't understand.

Comment: You can do that by iterating through `Base._decl_class_registry`

Comment: Iterating through `Base.__subclasses__()` also works

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Inspired by [Eevee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668355/sqlalchemy-get-model-from-table-name-this-may-imply-appending-some-function-to/23754464#comment24391616_11718281)'s comment:

```
def get_class_by_tablename(tablename):
  """Return class reference mapped to table.

  :param tablename: String with name of table.
  :return: Class reference or None.
  """
  for c in Base._decl_class_registry.values():
    if hasattr(c, '__tablename__') and c.__tablename__ == tablename:
      return c
```

Comment: Works great - for flask-sqlalchemy replace Base with db.Model as they are the same thing (more or less).

Comment: had to change `__tablename__` to `__table__` to get this to work

Answer (score 23):

So in SQLAlchemy version 1.4.x (which I updated to around 2020-03-16) it seems `_decl_class_registry` no longer exists.

I was able to work around using the new `registry` class attribute (which is not protected, so hopefully it wont be removed suddenly!).

```
Base.TBLNAME_TO_CLASS = {}

for mapper in Base.registry.mappers:
    cls = mapper.class_
    classname = cls.__name__
    if not classname.startswith('_'):
        tblname = cls.__tablename__
        Base.TBLNAME_TO_CLASS[tblname] = cls
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but its how I did it.

Answer (score 13):

Beware the [OrangeTux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23754464/4213715) answer does not take schemas in account. If you have table homonyms in different schemas use:

```
def get_class_by_tablename(table_fullname):
  """Return class reference mapped to table.

  :param table_fullname: String with fullname of table.
  :return: Class reference or None.
  """
  for c in Base._decl_class_registry.values():
    if hasattr(c, '__table__') and c.__table__.fullname == table_fullname:
      return c
```

`fullname` is a Table attribute see:

[github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L530-L532](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/7a4c40ff6b9d278529735c792c3ddfda60bd4a85/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L530-L532)

Answer (score 8):

Utility function for this has been added to [SQLAlchemy-Utils](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils). See [get_class_by_table docs](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orm_helpers.html#sqlalchemy_utils.functions.get_class_by_table) for more information. The solution in SQLAlchemy-Utils is able to cover single table inheritance scenarios as well.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa


def get_class_by_table(base, table, data=None):
    """
    Return declarative class associated with given table. If no class is found
    this function returns `None`. If multiple classes were found (polymorphic
    cases) additional `data` parameter can be given to hint which class
    to return.

    ::

        class User(Base):
            __tablename__ = 'entity'
            id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
            name = sa.Column(sa.String)


        get_class_by_table(Base, User.__table__)  # User class


    This function also supports models using single table inheritance.
    Additional data paratemer should be provided in these case.

    ::

        class Entity(Base):
            __tablename__ = 'entity'
            id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
            name = sa.Column(sa.String)
            type = sa.Column(sa.String)
            __mapper_args__ = {
                'polymorphic_on': type,
                'polymorphic_identity': 'entity'
            }

        class User(Entity):
            __mapper_args__ = {
                'polymorphic_identity': 'user'
            }


        # Entity class
        get_class_by_table(Base, Entity.__table__, {'type': 'entity'})

        # User class
        get_class_by_table(Base, Entity.__table__, {'type': 'user'})


    :param base: Declarative model base
    :param table: SQLAlchemy Table object
    :param data: Data row to determine the class in polymorphic scenarios
    :return: Declarative class or None.
    """
    found_classes = set(
        c for c in base._decl_class_registry.values()
        if hasattr(c, '__table__') and c.__table__ is table
    )
    if len(found_classes) > 1:
        if not data:
            raise ValueError(
                "Multiple declarative classes found for table '{0}'. "
                "Please provide data parameter for this function to be able "
                "to determine polymorphic scenarios.".format(
                    table.name
                )
            )
        else:
            for cls in found_classes:
                mapper = sa.inspect(cls)
                polymorphic_on = mapper.polymorphic_on.name
                if polymorphic_on in data:
                    if data[polymorphic_on] == mapper.polymorphic_identity:
                        return cls
            raise ValueError(
                "Multiple declarative classes found for table '{0}'. Given "
                "data row does not match any polymorphic identity of the "
                "found classes.".format(
                    table.name
                )
            )
    elif found_classes:
        return found_classes.pop()
    return None
```

Comment: This function takes the table object (the exact same one, `c.__table__ is table`), not a table name.

Comment: correct maybe @Konsta you can change the comparision to str(c.__table__) in your implementation or use __tablename__ cause most of the time we dont know the class only the table name then only we can use this function

Answer (score 6):

For sqlalchemy 1.4.x (and probably 2.0.x for the future readers too) You can nicely extend the [Erotemic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666783/10743742) answer to be more convenient when models are distributed across many files (such case is a primary reason for looking up ORM classes when doing proper OOP).

Take such class and make a `Base` from it:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

class BaseModel:

    @classmethod
    def model_lookup_by_table_name(cls, table_name):
        registry_instance = getattr(cls, "registry")
        for mapper_ in registry_instance.mappers:
            model = mapper_.class_
            model_class_name = model.__tablename__
            if model_class_name == table_name:
                return model


Base = declarative_base(cls=BaseModel)
```

Then declaring your models, even in separate modules, enables You to use `cls.model_lookup_by_table_name(...)` method without importing anything,
as long as You are deriving from a `Base`:

`user_models.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # ... and other columns

    def some_method(self):
        # successfully use lookup like this
        balance_model = self.model_lookup_by_table_name("balance")
        # ...
        return balance_model
```

`balance_models.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer

class Balance(Base):
    __tablename__ = "balance"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # ... other columns

    def some_method(self):
        # lookup works on every model
        user_model = self.model_lookup_by_table_name("user")
        # ...
        return user_model
```

And it works as expected:

```
>>> User().some_method()
<class 'balance_models.Balance'>
>>> Balance().some_method()
<class 'user_models.User'>
>>> Base.model_lookup_by_table_name("user")
<class 'user_models.User'>
>>> Base.model_lookup_by_table_name("balance")
<class 'balance_models.Balance'>
```

You can safely cache the output of this method using `functools.lru_cache` to improve performance (avoiding python `for` loop when it is not needed). Also, You can add more lookups the same way, e.g. by a class name (not only by a table name like in this example)

Answer (score 3):

Old thread, but none of the answers here worked for me working with Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1. and SQLAlchemy 1.4.32

As `db.Model` object you use in Flask-SQLAlchemy is practically identical to the `Base` model object in SQLAlchemy ORM, I think my answer below applies in the modern context.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668355/sqlalchemy-get-model-from-table-name-this-may-imply-appending-some-function-to/23754464?newreg=7f89400988544dcf9e49fd7db845e238#comment100994306_11668355) from @Supra621 seems to be the cleanest solution where you can simply do:

```py
def get_class_from_tablename(tablename):
  for c in Base.__subclasses__():
    if c.__tablename__ == tablename:
      return c
```

Additionally, if you'd rather access this table object using the registry like the majority of the old answers here:

```py
def get_class_from_tablename(tablename):
  for c in Base.registry._class_registry.data.values():
    if hasattr(c, '__tablename__') and c.__tablename__ == tablename:
      return c
```

Not sure from which version the attribute names change, but at least this works in both SQLAlchemy ORM and Flask SQLAlchemy (latest versions at the time of writing).

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with sqlalchemy automap, you need a slight modification. Took me couple minutes to tune it out:

```
def get_class_by_tablename(tablename, Base):
  for c in Base._decl_class_registry.values():
    if c.__table__.name == tablename:
      return c
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define a `__table_cls__` classmethod in `Base` or as a mixin. Note that I haven't tested this with any sort of inheritance. An example if augmenting `Base`:

```
# Python 3.7.2, SQLAlchemy 1.3.13
###
# app/models.py
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class Base(object):
    @classmethod
    def __table_cls__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        t = Table(*args, **kwargs)
        t.decl_class = cls
        return t

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

Contriving a table example:

```
# app/models.py
class Account(Base):  # Note this is the customized Base class
    __tablename__ = 'account'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    account_number = Column(String)
```

Testing in console:

```
# Python 3.7.2 Console
>>> from app import models as m
>>> account_table = m.Base.metadata.tables['account']
>>> account_table.__class__
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>

>>> account_table.decl_class
<class 'app.models.Account'>
```

As a function:

```
def get_class_by_table_name(table_name):
    tbl = Base.metadata.tables[table_name]
    return tbl.decl_class
```

Side note: since a lot of answers have referenced `Base._decl_class_registry`, the `declarative_base()` function also accepts a dictionary for the `class_registry` named parameter.

```
>>> registered_classes = {}
>>> Base = declarative_base(cls=Base, class_registry=registered_classes)
>>> registered_classes.keys()
dict_keys(['Account', '_sa_module_registry', 'AccountType', ...])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if things are different now or something, but in *relatively simple* circumstances you can create a lookup table after configuring your mappers like so:

```py
table_name_to_class = {m.tables[0].name: m.class_ for m in Base.registry.mappers}
```

Here's a full code sample for anyone who cares (sorry for mixing in the **pytest** junk, I'm in the middle of something and this was the easiest way to demo the code...)

```py
import pytest
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session

engine = sa.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost/test")
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_a"
    a_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_b"
    b_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("table_a.a_id"))


@pytest.fixture
def table_name_to_class():
    try:
        Base.metadata.create_all()
        Base.registry.configure()
        yield {m.tables[0].name: m.class_ for m in Base.registry.mappers}
    finally:
        Base.metadata.drop_all()


def test_table_lookup(table_name_to_class):
    assert table_name_to_class["table_a"] is A
    assert table_name_to_class["table_b"] is B

    with Session(bind=Base.metadata.bind) as session:
        session.add(table_name_to_class["table_a"](a_id=0))
        session.add(table_name_to_class["table_b"](b_id=0, a_id=0))
        session.add(table_name_to_class["table_b"](b_id=1, a_id=0))
        session.commit()

    assert engine.execute(""" SELECT COUNT(a_id) FROM table_a """).scalar() == 1
    assert engine.execute(""" SELECT COUNT(b_id) FROM table_b """).scalar() == 2
```

Answer (score -1):

I was going to delete this but I figure that the discussion in the comments might be useful for people who want to know about some good practices. Take this answer with a pinch of salt.

---

something like this does the trick:

```
def getModelFromTableName(sTable):
    """
    return the Model class with the given __tablename__
    """
    globals = globals()
    for k in globals:
        if type(globals[k]) == sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.DeclarativeMeta:
            try:
                if globals[k].__tablename__ == sTable:
                    return globals[k]
            except:
                pass
    return None
```

Comment: oh my goodness.  this is brittle all around, but _if nothing else_: you don't need to stringify the class to test what it is!  just check `issubclass(globals[k], Base)`!

Comment: @Eevee: hey, it works. sayap's comment makes sense... can you tell me how it is brittle? I know a try...except with no exception type is generally bad practice, and stringifying things isn't necessary (taken that out). What else?

Comment: `type(...) == ...` is also unnecessary; use `issubclass` with your base class or `isinstance` with the metaclass.  you could iterate over `globals.items()` instead of doing a key lookup multiple times.  a function like this should raise an exception on failure.  but most importantly, as soon as a model file like this gets bigger than a couple dozen tables, most developers will be inclined to _split it up_ which will break this code in ways that may not be immediately obvious.

Comment: I didn't know about `items()`, thanks. I don't see the downside of using `type` rather than `issubclass` or `isinstance`... Also, the problem I solved with this is one of finding the correct model class in a predefined scope. In my case the scope is global and that's convenient. If anyone wants to adapt this for their purposes then they should adapt it for their scope. Scope is not the issue being explored here. And solving scope issues shouldn't be very hard anyway. Creative use of importlib would do the trick, or context could be included as a parameter.

Comment: `type` is brittle and can be fooled in a lot of ways.  looking up things in a lexical scope should always be a last resort—in this case you already have the mapping you want, as the comment on your question indicates.

Comment: @Eevee: "the comment", what comment? If you are referring to my documentation string then I'm not sure what you mean. In what way do I already have a tablename to model class mapping? I know I have a model class to tablename mapping but that's not what I'm after

Comment: sayap's comment, above.  `Base._decl_class_registry` is a dict of declarative class names to classes.  you could iterate its `.values()` and check the table names.  or you could extend the declarative metaclass to create your own similar dict.