# Get all models from flask-sqlalchemy db

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

After a database is constructed in SQLAlchemy, I want to get all of the models, which is to say, the classes which represent them

```
>>> db
<SQLAlchemy engine='postgresql:///example'>
>>> ???
[<db.Model 'User'>, <db.Model 'Comment'>, <db.Model 'Article'>]
```

Can this be achieved? How?

I can get the tables decently, just not the models. Eg:

```
>>> for t in db.metadata.tables.items():
        print(t)
```

this gives the tables just not the models themselves

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several related questions, but I didn't see any exact duplicates.

Using your code to get the table names, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668355/sqlalchemy-get-model-from-table-name-this-may-imply-appending-some-function-to)'s accepted answer to get the classes, we can match the classes to the tablenames that are registered on your database.

```
classes, models, table_names = [], [], []
for clazz in db.Model._decl_class_registry.values():
    try:
        table_names.append(clazz.__tablename__)
        classes.append(clazz)
    except:
        pass
for table in db.metadata.tables.items():
    if table[0] in table_names:
        models.append(classes[table_names.index(table[0])])
```

Where `models` is the list of models registed on your database.

The try catch is required because a `<sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.clsregistry._ModuleMarker object>` will be included in the `for clazz in ...` loop, and it doesn't have a `__tablename__` attribute.

Answer (score 11):

If you only need the classes, there is an simpler solution. I came up with it based on [Celeo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26518401/1305139):

```
from flask import current_app

# This is to be generic (ie. no need to pass your actual SQLAlchemy instance)
# This way you can include it even in your own extension.
db = current_app.extensions['sqlalchemy'].db

[cls for cls in db.Model._decl_class_registry.values()
 if isinstance(cls, type) and issubclass(cls, db.Model)]
```

This doesn’t need all those extra helper variables, just queries the class registry, and filters out everything that is not a model.

Answer (score 10):

In SQLAlchemy 1.4, the `_decl_class_registry.values()` method has removed, you can use `db.Model.registry.mappers` instead:

```
models = {
    mapper.class_.__name__: mapper.class_
    for mapper in db.Model.registry.mappers
}
```

See the details in [this issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6080).

Answer (score 0):

this works in my case:  slightly shorter; more readable

```
models = []
for name, thing in db_table_creation.__dict__.iteritems():
    if isinstance(thing, sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.DeclarativeMeta) and hasattr(thing, '__tablename__'):
        models.append(thing)
```

Comment: where'd db_table_creation come from

Answer (score 0):

Here is my variation of [Celeo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514823/get-all-models-from-flask-sqlalchemy-db/26518401#26518401) with typing and succinct intermediary steps:

```
from ??? import db  # Import from wherever you have this, or use GergelyPolonkai's method to get a db object.
from typing import List, Dict, Union
from flask_sqlalchemy import DefaultMeta
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.clsregistry import _ModuleMarker

registered_classes: List[Union[DefaultMeta, _ModuleMarker]] = \
    [x for x in db.Model._decl_class_registry.values()]
registered_models: List[DefaultMeta] = \
    [x for x in registered_classes if isinstance(x, DefaultMeta)]
tables: List[DefaultMeta] = \
    [x for x in registered_models if hasattr(x, '__tablename__')]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do is:

```
import inspect
import mymodels

for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(mymodels):
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and hasattr(obj, '__tablename__'):
        print("model: %s %s"%(name,obj))
```