# SQLALchemy dynamic filter_by

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I know you can build dynamic filters for queries for SQLAlchemy by supplying `**kwargs` to `filter_by`.

For example

```
    filters = {'id': '123456', 'amount': '232'}
    db.session.query(Transaction).filter_by(**filters)
```

Below is my question:

What if I need to query by "greater than" or "less than" clauses?
For example (raw SQL):

```
 select * from transaction t 
 where t.amount > 10 and t.amount < 100;
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Instead of using `filter_by` I would recommend using `filter`, it gives you a lot more options.

For example (from the manual):

```
db.session.query(MyClass).filter(
    MyClass.name == 'some name',
    MyClass.id > 5,
)
```

In relation to your case:

```
filters = (
    Transaction.amount > 10,
    Transaction.amount < 100,
)
db.session.query(Transaction).filter(*filters)
```

Comment: Do we have and opportunity to make list of filters such you mentioned but that operators will be filled in dynamically with placeholders, I.e something like:  
`op = ">="
value=10
filter1 =  "f{Transaction.amount}  {op} {value}"
 filters =( filter1)
db.session.query(Transaction).filter(*filters)`

Comment: @Wolph: I will appreciate you answer too

Comment: @JavaSa all operators are available through the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module in Python as well. So instead of `a >= b` you can also use `operator.ge(a, b)`

Comment: Is there a way to do this with various tables objects? How do you properly get the table and column object from a query string in a Rest API?

Like if you perform a join and then want to sometimes filter the joined table. I'm trying to find a way to dynamically set the joined table's filter based on a query string

Comment: @DanielJerrehian There's no pretty way to get the table object from a string, but there are several solutions available: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668355/sqlalchemy-get-model-from-table-name-this-may-imply-appending-some-function-to
Once you're at that point you should be able to do a `getattr(table, column) == value` to create the filter.

Comment: Is there some good way available to achieve this in case of raw query

Answer (score 7):

```
def get_filter_by_args(dic_args: dict):
    filters = []
    for key, value in dic_args.items():  # type: str, any
        if key.endswith('___min'):
            key = key[:-6]
            filters.append(getattr(model_class, key) > value)
        elif key.endswith('___max'):
            key = key[:-6]
            filters.append(getattr(model_class, key) < value)
        elif key.endswith('__min'):
            key = key[:-5]
            filters.append(getattr(model_class, key) >= value)
        elif key.endswith('__max'):
            key = key[:-5]
            filters.append(getattr(model_class, key) <= value)
        else:
            filters.append(getattr(model_class, key) == value)
    return filters

dic_args = {
    'is_created': 1,
    'create_time__min': 1588125484029,
}
filters = get_filter_by_args(dic_args)
lst = session.query(model_class).filter(*filters)
```