# Converting string formatted query to SQLAlchemy format

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I created query in string format as i had many manipulations within. but couldn't combine the query with actually query:

```py
string='and_(ContentCard.release_date.between("2016-01-01","2017-12-31"),ContentCard.content_type =="Movie",ContentCard.language_codes =="ja",or_(genre_ids.ilike("%35%"),genre_ids.ilike("%16%")))'
```

I need something like

```py
query = query.filter(string)
```

If I tried directly, it gives me a format error. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can't do that. this is a method in a class

Comment: @r3a9670 what is suitable option to do this?

Comment: what you want grab from database ?

Comment: query = query.filter( and_(ContentCard.release_date.between("2016-01-01","2017-12-31"), ContentCard.content_type =="Movie", ContentCard.language_codes =="ja", or_(genre_ids.ilike("%35%"), genre_ids.ilike("%16%"))) )

Comment: i have to apply filters on perticular data I am fetching from DB, where number and types of filters are dynamic

Comment: i will recieve filter values like release_date = '2016-01-01','2017-12-31', content_type =Movie, language_codes  = 'ja.  

here everything is optional

Comment: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336520/sqlalchemy-dynamic-filter)