# Dynamically construct python sqlalchemy ORM filters

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have two tables,

```
class Values(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attribute_values'
                    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    attribute = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('attributes.id'), primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(JSON)
```

```
class Attributes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attributes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)

   user_attribute = db.relationship(Values, backref='attributes', primaryjoin=id == Values.attribute)
```

where values has attribute_id(foreign key) and value which is JSON.

Now i will get random filters like,  `emails.type == "work"`, `(emails.type == "work") and (emails.type == "home")` could be as nested as this one `((usertype !== "Employee") and (not ((emails.value LIKE "%example.com%") OR (emails.value LIKE "%example.org%")))) and ((usertype !== "Employee") and (not ((emails.value LIKE "%example.com%") OR (emails.value LIKE "%example.org%"))))`

in all of above examples,  `emails` is attribute in attributes table,  where in values table i will have `{'type':'home'}`.  Where ever (.)operator that means it is json.
even ```>,<,<=,>=" are possiblities.

How can i create sqlalchemy queries with these queries dynamically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLALchemy dynamic filter\_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885879/sqlalchemy-dynamic-filter-by)

Comment: It would have worked if conditions were simple

Comment: You would need to provide additional code/data, e.g. how are those queries being represented in e.g. JSON.  Also, you did mention operator, which can be constructed using the functions provided by the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.