# (Flask)-SQLAlchemy get corresponding model from column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask-SQLALchemy i have a model with columns:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):

    def my_method1(self, arg1):
        pass

    a = Column(String(), primary_key=True)
```

Now i have a function which accepts Columns as argument to retrieve some information from them:

```
def get_column_info(column):
    if column.primary_key:
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

Note that this is just an example, the get_column_info does much more than that in reality.

Now i want to be able to access the originating model in my get_column_info function. That is i want to be able to call my_method1()
from within get_column_info.

Is there a way i can retrieve the originating model from a column instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no proper out of the box method for doing this. Column object has `table` attribute which returns `__table__` attribute of the model but you can't get actual model from it. However (as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28831522/6682517) suggested) you can use [get_class_by_table](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orm_helpers.html#sqlalchemy_utils.functions.get_class_by_table) method in `sqlalchemy_utils` plugin:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import get_class_by_table

def get_model(column):
    return get_class_by_table(db.Model, column.__table__)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the function that i was looking for, i just implemented that myself according to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668355/sqlalchemy-get-model-from-table-name-this-may-imply-appending-some-function-to