# SQLAlchemy and explicit locking

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have multiple processes that can potentially insert duplicate rows into the database. These inserts do not happen very frequently (a few times every hour) so it is not performance critical.

I've tried an exist check before doing the insert, like so:

```
#Assume we're inserting a camera object, that's a valid SQLAlchemy ORM object that inherits from declarative_base...
try:
  stmt = exists().where(Camera.id == camera_id)
  exists_result = session.query(Camera).with_lockmode("update").filter(stmt).first()

  if exists_result is None:
    session.add(Camera(...)) #Lots of parameters, just assume it works
    session.commit()
except IntegrityError as e:
  session.rollback()
```

The problem I'm running into is that the `exist()` check doesn't lock the table, and so there is a chance that multiple processes could attempt to insert the same object at the same time. In such a scenario, one process succeeds with the insert and the others fail with an IntegrityError exception. While this works, it doesn't feel "clean" to me.

I would really like some way of locking the Camera table before doing the `exists()` check.

Comment: Why not simply use `UNIQUE` constraint, try to insert the new row and catch `IntegrityError` if it fails? What's "unclean" about this approach?

Comment: That's what I currently do, as seen in the code posted. It works, but the primary key counter gets incremented each time. So I end up with primary keys that are not sequential. I would like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 11):

Pehaps this might be of interest to you:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sqlalchemy/8WLhbsp2nls

> You can lock the tables by executing the SQL directly. I'm not sure what that looks like in Elixir, but in plain SA it'd be something like:
>
> ```
>  conn = engine.connect()
>  conn.execute("LOCK TABLES Pointer WRITE")
>  #do stuff with conn
>  conn.execute("UNLOCK TABLES")
> ```

Comment: Doesn't really help as I'm already specifying `with_lockmode("update")` in the exists() query, which should have locked the table.

Comment: SELECT..FOR UPDATE doesn't lock the whole table, only the rows that match the SELECT criterion, which is useless for INSERT of not-yet-existing rows.  You need to use SQL like "LOCK TABLE" but this depends on the database you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I meant this answer: You can lock the tables by executing the SQL directly.  I'm not sure 
what that looks like in Elixir, but in plain SA it'd be something like:

   conn = engine.connect()
   conn.execute("LOCK TABLES Pointer WRITE")
   ... do stuff with conn
   conn.execute("UNLOCK TABLES")

Comment: @AlexVhr, the OP's confusion about your link is why SO discourages link-only answers.  When you refer to a link, please quote the relevant context so they know what you're talking about.