# preventing multiple execution of a method synchronously in flask

Tags: flask

I have a method in my flask app that all the users can run it. I have to make sure that it is never get run multiple times at the same time because there are lots of database queries and changes to them in this code that if multiple users run it at the same time it produces wrong and unexpected results.

Is there any lock mechanism or queue for the methods in flask that I can use for this particular method?

Comment: It is database-related, right? Is it possible to start from db side?

Comment: If you are using flask-sqlalchemy, each time there is a server call through your view function or AJAX, there is a db session started which can be committed *just for that view function and session*

Comment: Something similar [was discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520340/sqlalchemy-and-explicit-locking) although this seems to focus more on avoiding duplicate inserts.  Perhaps your usecase would merit a job queue such as [`rq`](https://python-rq.org/) run with a single worker to ensure the jobs run one-at-a-time.  However this would require a `redis` server, and may involve a slight learning curve.

Comment: I'd suggest reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624289/value-based-thread-lock