# How to subclass a table by changing the primary columns?

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy

I would like to use SQLAlchemy to add some test fixtures to the database. It should should `get` or `set` the *value* accordingly. I was trying to create a model method like: `ProductsModel.ensure(name="Dettol")` that will ensure the data in the DB against the `name` column, where `Products` is defined like:

`Products`

```py
class Products(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    idn = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

`ProductsModel.ensure` will take care of doing the unique-row check against the *composite* keys (`name` in this case) and decide if it has to be *get* or *set*.

---

However, I can't modify the real `Products` table definition which is defined (elsewhere) with `id` as the primary key like this:

```py
class Products(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    idn = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

So, is it possible for me to inherit the table, and modify the primary keys for my test-fixture use case?

I tried something like this:

```py
class ProductsUnique(Products):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'productsunique',
        'polymorphic_on':Products.idn # Hoping that I could override idn.
    }
    idn = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

But it says:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column 'idn' on class <class '__main__.ProductsUnique'> conflicts with existing column 'products.idn'
```

I believe, setting `polymorphic_on` on the original table might resolve the issue; but the problem is that I **can't** do it there.

Is there a way to set this after the class has been defined? There seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/2792) similar to this in the SQLAlchemy repository.

PS: After reading a lot of posts, I think I am looking for something like Django's [get_or_create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546207/does-sqlalchemy-have-an-equivalent-of-djangos-get-or-create); but I would like to more clear about the [natural keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297156/fastest-way-to-insert-object-if-it-doesnt-exist-with-sqlalchemy/12298306#12298306) for my table. I am not sure if there are existing solutions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to modify the primary key in order to check whether a row exists? You can't use `Session.merge`, but you could implement the check yourself:

```
class Product:
    @classmethod
    def get_or_create(cls, name):
        query = session.query(Product).filter_by(name=name)
        result = query.one_or_none()
        if not result:
            result = Product(name=name)
            session.add(result)
            session.commit()
            # maybe load again here to prevent an unexpected one later
        return result
```

If you're worried about race conditions:

1. Add a unique constraint to the column
2. You should probably rewrite your tests