# SQLAlchemy: Check if object is already present in table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a class `Item` whose `id` is a primary key and auto-generated. Now I read data from some other external source, create an `Item` object, and need to check if this object is already present in my `items` table. How do I do it?

Comment: Is it a ``get_or_create`` scenario? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546207/does-sqlalchemy-have-an-equivalent-of-djangos-get-or-create

Comment: @DemianBrecht, thanks for the response, but no, it isn't.

Comment: @missingfaktor how do you know if it already exists? Based on the primary key? Or some other unique key?

Comment: @jadkik94, a set of unique attributes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use [exists()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists)

```
q = session.query(Item.id).filter(Item.email==email)
session.query(q.exists()).scalar()    # returns True or False
```

Answer (score 13):

You could query for items that have the same attributes and check if the count is greater than zero.

```
if session.query(Item.id).filter(Item.email==newItem.email,
                                 Item.type==newItem.type).count() > 0:
    // item exists
```

Comment: The `>0` is redundant since count() returns zero if no matches are found and a positive integer otherwise.

Comment: @kalu: "Explicit is better than implicit." -- The Zen of Python

Comment: Using count makes the database do more work then it needs to. See my answer below for an efficient method.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something similar to this:

```
from sqlalchemy import exc

try:
    session.add(item)
    session.commit()
except exc.IntegrityError:
    session.rollback()
    print 'This item fails one of the unique/foreign key checks!'
except:
    print 'There was another error'
    raise
else:
    print 'Everything is OK'
```

This has the problem that it acts upon committing, and then rolls back...

Another option, if you can check the properties individually, then this might work:

```
session.query(Item).filter_by(x=item.x, y=item.y).count() == 0
```