# does sqlalchemy have an equivalent to datamapper's first_or_create method?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

using datamapper, if you want to "either find the first resource matching some given criteria or just create that resource if it can't be found, you can use #first_or_create."

i am using flask-sqlalchemy and am wondering if there is a similar feature.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is some things in `django` named `get_or_create` you can create somethings like that for `sqlalachemy`

```
def get_or_create(session, model, **kwargs):
    instance = session.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
    if instance:
        return instance
    else:
        instance = model(**kwargs)
        return instance
```

from here: python - Does SQLAlchemy have an equivalent of Django's get_or_create? - Stack Overflow -> [Does SQLAlchemy have an equivalent of Django's get_or_create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546207/does-sqlalchemy-have-an-equivalent-of-djangos-get-or-create)