# SQLAlchemy - Auto Lookup Foreign Key Relationship for Insert

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get an SQLAlchemy ORM class to automatically:

either lookup the foreign key id for a field

OR

for entries where the field isn't yet in foreign key table, add the row to the foreign key table - and use the auto generated id in the original table.

To illustrate:

**Class Definition**

```
class EquityDB_Base(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}
    __mapper_args__= {'always_refresh': True}

    id =  Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

def fk(tablename, nullable=False):
    return Column("%s_id" % tablename, Integer,
               ForeignKey("%s.id" % tablename),
               nullable=nullable)

class Sector(EquityDB_Base, Base):
    name = Column(String(40))

class Industry(EquityDB_Base, Base):
    name = Column(String(40))
    sector_id = fk('sector')
    sector = relationship('Sector', backref='industries')

class Equity(EquityDB_Base, Base):
    symbol = Column(String(10), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(40))
    industry_id = fk('industry')
    industry = relationship('Industry', backref='industries')
```

**Using the Class to Set Industry and Sector**

```
for i in industry_record[]:
    industry = Industry(id=i.id, 
                    name=i.name,
                    sector=Sector(name=i.sector_name))
    session.merge(industry)
```

**Result**
Unfortunately, when I run this - the database adds individual rows to the sector table for each duplicate use of 'sector_name' - for instance, if 10 industries use 'Technology' as their sector name, I get 10 unique sector_id for each one of the 10 industries.

What I WANT - is for each time a sector name is presented that is already in the database, for it to auto-resolve to the appropriate sector_id

I am clearly just learning SQLAlchemy, but can't seem to figure out how to enable this behavior.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See answer to a similar question [create_or_get entry in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20253201/99594).
Applying the same logic, you would have something like this:

```
def create_or_get_sector(sector_name):
    obj = session.query(Sector).filter(Sector.name == sector_name).first()
    if not obj:
        obj = Sector(name = sector_name)
        session.add(obj)
    return obj
```

and use it like below:

```
for i in industry_record[:]:
    industry = Industry(id=i.id, 
                    name=i.name,
                    sector=create_or_get_sector(sector_name=i.sector_name))
    session.merge(industry)
```

*One thing you should be careful about is which `session` instance is used there in the `create_or_get_sector`.*