# (dataframe.to_sql with reference_or_insert): How to automatically insert a missing record in a referenced table when a foreign key is not found?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, pandas-to-sql

### Description

I am trying to migrate data from a Pandas DataFrame to a MySQL database table but that data has some inconsistencies that I want to work around though **I have not yet figured out a way to**. Any help in figuring this out will be very much appreciated.

Example of the data I have:

**user_type** (table)

| code | detail |
| --- | --- |
| a | Secretary |
| b | Accountant |

**user_df** (DataFrame with the data I want to migrate to the **user** table)

| id | name | user_type_code (FK: user_type) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane Doe | a |
| 2 | John Doe | a |
| 3 | James Doe | b |
| 4 | Jeff Doe | c |
| 5 | Jennifer Doe | d |

As you can notice from the above data, the `user_type_code` with values ***c*** & ***d*** cannot be found in the **user_type** table.

**What I want to achieve** is to automatically insert those `user_type` missing data with dummy information to accommodate for the need of being corrected in the future and keep all the user records.

**user_type** table (*how I want it to be at the end*)

| code | detail |
| --- | --- |
| a | Secretary |
| b | Accountant |
| c | Unknown c |
| d | Unknown d |

---

### My Current Implementation

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert
from sqlalchemy.exc import NoReferenceError

# I want to add an implementation of inserting the dummy data in the referenced table (user_type) in this function
def insert_ignore_on_duplicates(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    """ Insert ignore on duplicate primary keys """
    try:
        insert_stmt = insert(table.table).values(list(data_iter))
        on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(
            insert_stmt.inserted
        )
        conn.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
    except NoReferenceError as error:
        print("Error: {}".format(error))

db_engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@localhost:3306/")

user_df = pd.DataFrame()  # Assume this contains all the users' data

user_df.to_sql(
    "user",
    con=db_engine,
    if_exists="append",
    index=False,
    method=insert_ignore_on_duplicates,
    chunksize=5000,
)
```

I am seeking help to figure out how this `insert_ignore_on_duplicates` function/method can be modified to allow the automatic insertion of missing foreign key references or any other approach that can perform that.

---

### Some Related Questions I Found

- [Does SQLAlchemy have an equivalent of Django's get_or_create?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2546207/13741871)
- [SQLAlchemy Automatically Create Entry If Doesn't Exist As Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30793362/13741871)
- [Fastest way to insert object if it doesn't exist with SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12297156/13741871)

---

**P.S.** The reason why I need this implementation is because the data is large (>4 million records) and it contains numerous foreign keys that are not present hence **cannot practically be checked manually**. Adding these primary dummy data will help in keeping all the data and allowing suitable correction in the future, perhaps updating the record ***c: Unknown c*** to ***c: Auditor***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need is a list of the missing codes in the `user_type` table. You can get that like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# example data
user_type = pd.DataFrame(
    [("a", "Secretary"), ("b", "Accountant")], columns=["code", "detail"]
)
# (the above would actually be retrieved via `pd.read_sql_table("user_type", engine)`)
user_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (1, "Jane Doe", "a"),
        (2, "John Doe", "a"),
        (3, "James Doe", "b"),
        (4, "Jeff Doe", "c"),
        (5, "Jennifer Doe", "d"),
    ],
    columns=["id", "name", "user_type_code"],
)

# real code starts here
user_type_code_list = user_type["code"].unique()
user_df_code_list = user_df["user_type_code"].unique()
user_types_to_add = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (f"{x}", f"Unknown {x}")
        for x in user_df_code_list
        if x not in user_type_code_list
    ],
    columns=["code", "detail"],
)
print(user_types_to_add)
"""
  code     detail
0    c  Unknown c
1    d  Unknown d
"""
```

You can then use

```py
user_types_to_add.to_sql("user_type", db_engine, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

to add the missing rows to the `user_type` table, followed by

```py
user_df.to_sql("user", db_engine, index=False, if_exists="append", …)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It worked and I liked your approach since it identifies and inserts all the missing `user_types` before going on to inserting users. I think that approach is better than what I was thinking of checking that on each and every insertion of a `user`.