# SQLAlchemy check before insert in Python

Tags: python, exception, sqlalchemy, race-condition

I have a question about a more proper/efficient way how to check if a entry is already in a database table.

Suppose that I have a table called `Foo` with single attribute and `Name` which is also ***unique***.

What is a better way to check before insert if there is already an entry with such name? I can think of two alternatives:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, String, \
create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"

    name = Column(String(), primary_key=True)

    @staticmethod
    def silent_insert1(name):
            if not session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.name == name).first():
                    foo = Foo()
                    foo.name = name
                    session.add(foo)
                    session.commit()
            else:
                    print("already exists 1")

    @staticmethod
    def silent_insert2(name):
            try:
                    foo = Foo()
                    foo.name = name
                    session.add(foo)
                    session.commit()
            except(IntegrityError):
                    print("already exists 2")


engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(engine)()

Foo.silent_insert1(1)
Foo.silent_insert2(1)
```

In the first **silent_insert1**, there is of course a race condition. The second seems more bullet proof.

Which one is better? Is even a better way or recommended way how to check this?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21146492/443900 has a generic solution similar to your second method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should just put the `session.add` in the `try/except`

secondly this is a a question of philosophy.  you will not get a definitive answer.

the two styles are know as **look before you leap (LBYL)** , this style uses an if statement ahead of time to see if you should do it.

the 2nd style is known as **Easier To Ask Forgiveness, than Permission(EAFP)**, this style assumes that it will work and catches and handles the exception that is raised in the event that the rules are broken. as a general rule python programmers tend to favor EAFP, but like any rule there are many many many exceptions

Comment: I think you'd also want a `session.flush` before the `try`, to ensure any previous errors would be raised before the start of the block.

Comment: What is the exception that violtes UniqueKeyConstraiints?