# One to many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following one-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy.

```
class Application(Base):
    __tablename__  = "application"

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)        
    organization_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('organization.id'))
    organization = relationship("Organization", uselist=False, back_populates="applications")
```

and

```
class Organization(Base):
    __tablename__  = "organization"

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    name = Column("name", String(128), unique = True, nullable = False)
    applications = relationship("Application", back_populates="organization")
```

To put the relationship in words, "one organization can have many applications and an application can have a single organization".

The way I infer it is that the `Organization` class is the parent and the `Application` class is the child.

I have a .csv file that contains a list of **applications**. I'm parsing the list to create an instance of `Application` and `Organization` from each row. I then set `application.organization = organization`, and then do `session.add(application)`.

When I the application to the database, if the organization that is added in turn is being added the first time, it's inserted correctly. But when an application is found that has the same organization as one inserted before it complains of an error -

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062,
>   "Duplicate entry 'MICROSOFT' for key 'name'")

I understand that this is because this organization already exists in the DB.

Won't SQLAlchemy take care of this case? If not, how do I handle this on my end?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably creating a new Organization each time instead of grabbing the already existing one (if it exists).

This code should point you in the right direction

```
# Organization name from your CSV
org_name = 'MICROSOFT'

# Get Organization if it already exists
application.organization = Organization.query.filter(Organization.name == org_name ).first()

# If the Organization doesn't exist, create a new one
if application.organization is None:
    application.organization = Organization(name=org_name)
```

Comment: So SQLAlchemy doesn't take care of this automatically?

Comment: @KunalShah - What is "this" exactly? You have told it to not allow organizations to have the same name, and then you try to make two organizations with the same name. It raises an error because you have explicitly asked it to do so under this circumstance (`unique = True`).

Comment: Won't SQLAlchemy do the equivalent of create if not exists?

Comment: Not built in, but you can create one. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546207/does-sqlalchemy-have-an-equivalent-of-djangos-get-or-create) question.