# Postgres race condition involving subselect and foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, foreign-keys, subquery

We have 2 tables defined as follows

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
  foo_id BIGINT UNIQUE,
  foo_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES foo (name)
);
```

I've noticed that when executing the following two queries concurrently

```
INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('BAZ')
```

```
INSERT INTO bar (foo_name, foo_id) VALUES ('BAZ', (SELECT id FROM foo WHERE name = 'BAZ'))
```

it is possible under certain circumstances to end up inserting a row into `bar` where `foo_id` is `NULL`. The two queries are executed in different transactions, by two completely different processes.

How is this possible? I'd expect the second statement to either fail due to a foreign key violation (if the record in `foo` is not there), or succeed with a non-null value of `foo_id` (if it is).

What is causing this race condition? Is it due to the subselect, or is it due to the timing of when the foreign key constraint is checked?

We are using isolation level "read committed" and postgres version 10.3.

**EDIT**

I think the question was not particularly clear on what is confusing me. The question is about how and why 2 different states of the database were being observed during the execution of a single statement. The subselect is observing that the record in foo as being absent, whereas the fk check sees it as present. If it's just that there's no rule preventing this race condition, then this is an interesting question in itself - why would it not be possible to use transaction ids to ensure that the same state of the database is observed for both?

Comment: Don't ask us how it's possible, that's asking us to rewrite the documentaiton with a bespoke tutorial & asking us to address your wrong reasoning with no idea what your reasoning is. Say what you expect & say why you expect it with justification by reference to documentation.

Comment: If the first insert is not committed before the second one is executed this is absolutely possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I think my question was not particularly clear. I've edited it, adding a clarification at the end.

Comment: Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of editing time. Adding to something unclear doesn't make it clear. Again: if you don't give what you think is a model for SQL concurrent transactions, justified by documentaiton, & how it justifies your expectations, you are just asking us to write yet another presentation & without us able to say where your current misconceptions are, which is too broad & is ineffective. The reason you get what you get is, that's how the system is defined to behave.

Comment: This link gives an example for repetable read in postgre. Look at example 2 : https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2020/02/14/isolation-repeatable-read-postgresql-mysql.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The subselect in the `INSERT INTO bar` cannot see the new row concurrently inserted in `foo` because the latter is not committed yet.

But by the time that the query that checks the foreign key constraint is executed, the `INSERT INTO foo` has committed, so the foreign key constraint doesn't report an error.

A simple way to work around that is to use the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level for the `INSERT INT bar`. Then the foreign key check uses the same snapshot as the `INSERT`, it won't see the newly committed row, and a constraint violation error will be thrown.

Comment: The question was about how and why 2 different states of the database were being observed during the execution of a single statement. The subselect is observing that the record in foo as being absent, whereas the fk check sees it as present. You haven't addressed that at all. If it's just that there's no rule preventing this race condition, then this is an interesting question in itself - why would it not be possible to use transaction ids to ensure that the same state of the database is observed for both?

Comment: The foreign key constraint is not on the nullable column, it's on the `foo_name` column.  In the cases I'm confused about, the insert statement is inserting a non null value into `foo_name`, which means that `BAZ` is there... but the subselect is not seeing it.

Comment: Finally the light is dawning on me. I hadn't understood your problem correctly. See my modified answer.

Comment: @cppbeginner "why 2 different states of the database were being observed" - because you are using `read committed` isolation level. This level is not enough to prevent what you are seeing.

Comment: Yes I agree that's the answer. I'm not sure what else I was expecting anyone to say. It still surprised me that a single statement can behave like this though, at any isolation level. As this question now has a bounty I'll wait before that's about to expire before accepting an answer though.

Comment: Let's say it is an implementation artifact - the foreign key is checked by a second query executed via SPI, and that gets its own snapshot in `READ COMMITTED`. It might be non-trivial to change that (imagine a deferred constraint, where this is exactly what you want), and you can easily avoid it with `REPEATABLE READ`, which is not any more expensive. I agree that it is slightly surprising.

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce a race condition like this? Can we pause execution of the query after it's evaluated the subquery?

Comment: @Andrew Sometimes you can add a call to `pg_sleep()` at the right place in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Logic suggests that ordering of the commands (including the sub-query), combined with when Postgres checks of constraints (which is not necessarily immediate) could cause the issue. Therefore you could

- Have the second command start first
- Have the `SELECT` component run and return NULL
- First command starts and inserts row
- Second command inserts the row (with the 'name' field and a NULL)
- FK reference check is successful as 'name' exists

Re deferrable constraints see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-set-constraints.html and https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-08-27-deferrable-sql-constraints.html

Suggested answers

- Have a not null check on BAR for Foo_Id, or included as part of foreign key checks
- Rewrite the two commands to run consecutively rather than simultaneously (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed have a race condition. Without some sort of locking or use of a transaction to sequence the events, there is no rule precluding the sequence

1. The sub select of the `bar` INSERT is performed, yielding `NULL`
2. The INSERT into `foo`
3. The INSERT into `bar`, which now does not have any FK violation, but does have a NULL.

Since of course this is the toy version of your real program, I can't recommend how best to fix it. If it makes sense to require these events in a particular sequence, then they can be in a transaction on a single thread. In some other situation, you might prohibit inserting directly into `foo` and `bar` (REVOKE permissions as necessary) and allow modifications only through a function/procedure, or through a view that has triggers (possibly rules).

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous plpgsql block will help you avoid the race conditions (by making sure that the inserts run sequentially within the same transaction) without going deep into Postgres internals:

```sql
do language plpgsql
$$
declare
 v_foo_id bigint;
begin
 INSERT into foo (name) values ('BAZ') RETURNING id into v_foo_id;
 INSERT into bar (foo_name, foo_id) values ('BAZ', v_foo_id);
end;
$$;
```

or using plain SQL with a CTE in order to avoid switching context to/from plpgsql:

```sql
with t(id) as 
(
 INSERT into foo (name) values ('BAZ') RETURNING id
) 
INSERT into bar (foo_name, foo_id) values ('BAZ', (select id from t));
```

And, btw, are you sure that the two inserts in your example are executed in the same transaction in the right order? If not then the short answer to your question is "MVCC" since the second statement is not atomic.

Comment: The whole point of the question is how that can happen if the two inserts are **not** part of the same transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - right, I somehow omitted an important sentence in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more likely a scenario where both queries executed one after another but transaction is not committed.

Process 1

> INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('BAZ')

Transaction not committed but Process 2 execute next query

> INSERT INTO bar (foo_name, foo_id) VALUES ('BAZ', (SELECT id FROM foo WHERE name = 'BAZ'))

In this case process 2 query will wait until process 1 transaction isn't committed.

From PostgreSQL doc :

UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT FOR UPDATE, and SELECT FOR SHARE commands behave the same as SELECT in terms of searching for target rows: they will only find target rows that were committed as of the command start time. However, such a target row might have already been updated (or deleted or locked) by another concurrent transaction by the time it is found. In this case, the would-be updater will wait for the first updating transaction to commit or roll back (if it is still in progress).