# Debugging (displaying) SQL command sent to the db by SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an ORM class called Person, which wraps around a person table:

After setting up the connection to the db etc, I run the statement:

```py
people = session.query(Person).all()
```

The person table does not contain any data (as yet), so when I print the variable `people`, I get an empty list.

I renamed the table referred to in my ORM class `People`, to `people_foo` (which does not exist).

I then run the script again. I was surprised that no exception was thrown when attempting to access a table that does not exist.

I therefore have the following 2 questions:

1. How may I setup SQLAlchemy so that it propagates db errors back to the script?
2. How may I view (i.e. print) the SQL that is being sent to the db engine?

If it helps, I am using PostgreSQL.

**[Edit]**

I am writing a package. In my `__main__.py` script, I have the following code (shortened here):

```
### __main__.py
import common # imports logging and defines logging setup funcs etc

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def main():    
    parser = OptionParser(usage="%prog [options] <commands>",
                          version="%prog 1.0")

    commands = OptionGroup(parser, "commands")

    parser.add_option(
        "-l",
        "--logfile",
        dest="logfile",
        metavar="FILE",
        help="log to FILE. if not set, no logging will be done"
    )

    parser.add_option(
        "--level",
        dest="loglevel",
        metavar="LOG LEVEL",
        help="Debug level. if not set, level will default to low"
    )

    # Set defaults if not specified
    if not options.loglevel:
        loglevel = 1
    else:
        loglevel = options.loglevel

    if not options.logfile:
        logfilename = 'datafeed.log'
    else:
        logfilename = options.logfile

    common.setup_logger(False, logfilename, loglevel) 

       # and so on ...



        #### dbfuncs.py


import logging

    # not sure how to 'bind' to the logger in __main__.py
    logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)

    engine = create_engine('postgres://postgres:pwd@localhost:port/dbname', echo=True)
```

**[Edit2]**

Common module sets the logger up correctly, and I can use the logger in my other modules that import common.

However in `dbfuncs` module, I am getting the following error/warning:

> No handlers could be found for logger "sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine

Comment: Indention of code is broken, I see no `common.setup_logger()` call (assuming it configure logging properly) here. Also, you don't need `echo=True` when using logging.

Comment: @denis: Yes the logger is setup correctly in the common module - I am able to log in other modules. For the dbfuncs.py module. I get the error: No handlers could be found for logger "sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine

Comment: "No handlers could be found for logger" means root logger has no handlers, i.e. logger _is not_ configured properly yet. Probably you have configured some specific (not root) logger only (and so you can use it) or you configured it _after_ it's used first time.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

In addition to `echo` parameter of `create_engine()` there is a more flexible way: configuring `logging` to echo engine statements:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

See [Configuring Logging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#configuring-logging) section of documentation for more information.

Comment: @dennis: this is what I would rather do - to log to file instead opf console. I am already using logging in the __main__.py of my package (see my edited code) - after making the changes you recommended, now the messages are no longer appearing on console (good), but they are also not appearing in the log file (bad). Could you clarify how to get the messages logged to file?

Comment: Is there any way to add pretty printing? The way my queries are outputted by default is a small disaster.

Comment: So is this impossible to log into a file in the end? I have searched deep into the docs and stack overflow, but nobody seems to care about this problem, even when the question is clearly asked by someone like morpheous did above. Is there something obvious here?

Comment: @RomainVincent It's possible to direct logged information wherever you want, including file, by configuring logging.

Comment: Just put those bunch of code in your dbcon or anywhere

Answer (score 144):

You can see the SQL statements being sent to the DB by passing `echo=True` when the engine instance is created (usually using the `create_engine()` or `engine_from_config()` call in your code).

For example:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgres://foo/bar', echo=True)
```

By default, logged statements go to stdout.