# With specific dates AND times in a database column, how do I query for all records on a specific day?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Convoluted title. I am using python sqlalchemy with a postgresql database.

I have a database that stores `Events`, and each event record has a `starttime` and a `endtime` column. Both of the aforementioned columns are in this format:

`2015-06-22 13:00:00`

How can I therefore query the database for all `Events` from a specific day. Thereby ignoring the "time" part of the `starttime` and `endtime` columns?

For example I tried:

```
query = Event.query.filter(Event.starttime=='2015-06-22', Event.endtime=='2015-06-22').all()
```

However this came up with 0 results, I am assuming perhaps this is because the absence of hh/mm/ss makes the query 'assume' that I mean 00:00:00.

I also tried

```
query = Event.query.filter(Event.starttime>='2015-06-22', Event.endtime<='2015-06-22').all()
```

But this came up with 0 results as well, I assume for the same reason as the previous.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is the query that gets sent to the DB:

```
SELECT events.id AS events_id, events.summary AS events_summary, events.starttime AS events_starttime, events.endtime AS events_endtime, events.parentcal AS events_parentcal, events.userid AS events_userid 
FROM events 
WHERE events.starttime >= :starttime_1 AND events.endtime < :endtime_1
```

Comment: It would be most helpful to log the query that actually gets sent to the db, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950385/debugging-displaying-sql-command-sent-to-the-db-by-sqlalchemy how to get these logs.

Comment: Try to use `.filter(Event.starttime>='2015-06-22', Event.endtime<'2015-06-23')`.

Comment: Updated with query now.

Comment: What type is the column?

Comment: Columns are defined in my Models.py file as:

`starttime = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)`
`endtime = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using actual datetime objects.  SQLAlchemy can interpret them.

```
from datetime import datetime

starttime = datetime.strptime('2015-06-22', '%Y-%m-%d')
endtime = datetime.strptime('2015-06-23', '%Y-%m-%d')
query = Event.query.filter(Event.starttime>=starttime, Event.endtime<endtime).all()
```

For more information on parsing datetime strings check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)