# SQLAlchemy: What happens when calling list() on a Query object?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

So I get that when I call list() on a Query object, that executes the query and returns the results as a list.

What I'm wondering is what exactly is happening in the source code to make the Query fire SQL and grab the results.

Comment: Might want to enable logging (as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950385/debugging-displaying-sql-command-sent-to-the-db-by-sqlalchemy) ) and see what query actually gets executed when list is called.

Answer (score 1):

When do you `list(query)`, python invokes the method `__iter__()`, as for any container, for the class `Query`.

This method initializes context and eventually calls `_execute_and_instances()`, and internal method of class `Query`, which gets the connection from the session and executes the query statement.

```
def _execute_and_instances(self, querycontext):
    conn = self._connection_from_session(
        mapper=self._mapper_zero_or_none(),
        clause=querycontext.statement,
        close_with_result=True)

    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
    return loading.instances(self, result, querycontext)
```

So the query is executed just when the `list` object is created.

It's not much detail, and I hope it is enough to answer your question. Maybe some context on why you are asking would allow to go into more relevant details. Hope it helps anyway.

**EDIT:** After clarifications via comments, as for your second question (i.e. how to add a traceback of your call as a comment in the query, to be logged in the server): I don't think is feasible just modifying in one single point.

Most queries go through the object `Query`, and its method `_compile_context` is a common point where the query is composed. If you launch either a usual query (a select with filters and so on) or a delete, it will go through this method.

However, `session.add` is completely different. At the moment of adding the object not much is really done (regarding the query I mean; of course the new object is registered). The objects are only inserted when you perform `commit` (as expected btw). `session.flush` starts this process. At that point, you have available `SQLAlchemy`'s `mapper` and you could get the instance of the object you are actually adding (e.g. an instance of your class `User`). If you have added the traceback at the moment of creating your instance, you could recover it here and add it to the query as a comment.

At any rate, this would not be easy at all, difficult to maintain as well, while it is only for debugging. I understand what you are trying to do but it is too much effort for a result which is not so great (in my opinion).

Comment: This is very helpful! The context would be that I'm trying to write a wrapper around session.query, session.add, session.delete, etc. that inserts a comment into the query sent to the SQL server with a traceback of when the relevant method is called. What would make it easier is if there is one particular lower level method that is called by all of these that I can wrap instead of doing them each individually

Comment: Ok, but you want to add your stuff when the query is actually sent to the server? I mean, `session.add` composes a query (I don't know if it does it just at the point of the call, I would have to check it), but that query is not sent to the server until `commit`. The same with a `select`, you first compose the query but it is actually sent when you need the data. I think the common point you are looking for, if you want the point in which the query is actually sent, it is `connection.execute`.

Comment: 2nd question: what exactly you want to add? If it is only a comment, `SQLAlchemy` has really loads of logging (@TJ1S has already provided a link).

Comment: I want to add my stuff when the query is composed, i.e. when `session.add` is called. I want to make the comment show up in the actual query so that it's recorded in the MySQL general log. The comment should basically just be the first line of a traceback saying which file and which line the query came from.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Then your point is not `connection.execute`. You could do it somewhere in the `Query` object. Let me take a look and I'll get back to you if I find something. (Be patient, it is a bit late in my timezone and might leave it for tomorrow.)

Comment: Hi. No, I don't think there is a common point as you are requesting. The method `_compile_context` of  `Query` is common for most operations, e.g. for a normal query and a delete, but the `session.add` is done in a completely different way, without the query, I can't figure it out. I give up, sorry and good luck!