# SQLAlchemy query shows error "Can't join table/selectable 'workflows' to itself"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I wrote a SQL query that I'm trying to port to SQLAlchemy, but receive the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't join table/selectable 'workflows' to itself
```

SQL (working):

```sql
SELECT
   w.user_id, COUNT(l.id) 
FROM
   logs as l
INNER JOIN
   workflows as w 
   ON l.workflow_id = w.id
WHERE
   l.type = 's'
   AND l.timestamp > extract(epoch from now()) - 86400
GROUP BY
   w.user_id;
```

SQLAlchemy (not working):

```
session.query(
   Workflow.user_id, func.count(Log.id)
).join(
   Workflow, Workflow.id == Log.workflow_id
).filter(
   Log.type == 's', Log.timestamp > time.time() - 86400
).group_by(
   Workflow.user_id
).all()
```

Here is the expected output:

```
+----------+---------+
|  user_id |  count  |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 5       |
| 2        | 10      |
+----------+---------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Part

```
.query(Workflow.user_id, func.count(Log.id))
```

adds both `Workflow` and `Log` to your query. The first model is marked as primary table and others are marked as secondary. If there is no calls to `.join()` afterwards, both primary and secondary tables will be added to the `FROM` clause. If there are calls to `.join()` it will move table it receives to the `JOIN` clause. The important thing here is that `.join()` can be applied only to the secondary table.

The problem is that your call to

```
.join(Workflow, Workflow.id == Log.workflow_id)
```

tries to mark primary table as joined. To fix issue you need to join secondary table:

```
.join(Log, Workflow.id == Log.workflow_id)
```

---

You can add [`echo=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950434/1377864) to see SQL generated by SQLAlchemy. It's really convenient to debug your queries. Or you can [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25563491/1377864) single query to see generated SQL.

Comment: Hmm.. I changed the SQLAlchemy to `session.query(Workflow.user_id, func.count(Log.id)).filter(Log.type == 's').filter(Log.timestamp > time.time() - 86400).group_by(Workflow.user_id).all()`. This was the generated SQL: `SELECT workflows.user_id AS workflows_user_id, count(logs.id) AS count_1
FROM workflows, logs
WHERE logs.type = %(type_1)s AND logs.timestamp > %(timestamp_1)s GROUP BY workflows.user_id`. It returns a count of 2 for both user_ids which is incorrect - it should be 5 for user_id 1 and 10 for user_id 2.

Comment: Yeah, that's because tables are not joined. As an easy solution you can add `Workflow.id == Log.workflow_id` into you `.where()` method. Or try `.join(Log, Workflow.id == Log.workflow_id)` to configure proper join (not sure weather it works).

Answer (score 2):

As noted before, the primary entity of your query is `Workflow`, and so the join is trying to join `Workflow` to itself, which is not possible, at least not without using aliases.

In addition to simply reordering the join you can also explicitly control the left hand side of the join using [`Query.select_from()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from):

```
session.query(
    Workflow.user_id, func.count(Log.id)
).select_from(
    Log
).join(
    Workflow, Workflow.id == Log.workflow_id
).filter(
    Log.type == 's', Log.timestamp > time.time() - 86400
).group_by(
    Workflow.user_id
).all()
```