# SQLAlchemy Coalesce and Join

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm having a lot of trouble converting my sql query to sqlalchemy. I haven't been able to find any resources doing what I am trying to do.

The query I am trying to convert is:

```
SELECT 
     COALESCE(d.manager_name, e.name) AS name,
     COALESCE(d.department_name, e.department_name) AS department
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN department d ON e.id = d.id 
WHERE e.date = '2018-11-05'
```

In sqlalchemy I came up with:

```
  query = self.session.query(
            func.coalesce(Department.manager_name, Employee.name),
            func.coalesce(Department.department_name, Employee.department_name)).join(Department, 
                    Employee.id == Department.id,
                ).filter(
                    Employee.date == '2018-11-05',
                )
```

But keep getting the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't join table/selectable 'Department' to itself.
```

WHY?! The statements are exact!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766950/sqlalchemy-query-shows-error-cant-join-table-selectable-workflows-to-itself?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Department` is the leftmost item in your query, joins take place against it. To control what is considered the first – or the "left" – entity in the join use [`Query.select_from()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from):

```
query = self.session.query(
        func.coalesce(Department.manager_name, Employee.name),
        func.coalesce(Department.department_name, Employee.department_name)).\
    select_from(Employee).\
    outerjoin(Department, Employee.id == Department.id).\
    filter(Employee.date == '2018-11-05')
```

This behaviour is also explained in the ORM tutorial under ["Querying with Joins"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins), and [`Query.join()`: "Controlling what to Join From"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join).

Your query construct was also using `Query.join()`, though the raw SQL had `LEFT JOIN`. In that case [`Query.outerjoin()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.outerjoin) or [`join(..., isouter=True)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join.params.isouter) should be used.