# Printing the SQLAlchemy Query in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I need to know the way of getting the SQLAlchemy query printed with values.

I can be able to print the query which is getting processed, But it is not showing the values instead it just showing the field name itself.

```
SELECT recordsets.id AS recordsets_id, recordsets.version AS recordsets_version
FROM recordsets 
WHERE recordsets.domain_id = :domain_id_1 
AND recordsets.tenant_id IN (:tenant_id_1, :tenant_id_2) 
AND recordsets.name IN (:name_1, :name_2)
```

So instead of :name_1, :name_2 or :tenant_id_1, :tenant_id_2 I need to see the values itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating your engine you have the possibility to turn on logging, by setting `echo` on `True`. That will print all queries with their parameters.

Example:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@hostname/dbname",
                        encoding='latin1', echo=True)
```

See: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html#engine-creation-api

For your example the output will look like:

```
2015-11-16 15:50:25,137 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT recordsets.id AS recordsets_id, recordsets.version AS recordsets_version
FROM recordsets 
WHERE recordsets.domain_id = :domain_id_1 
AND recordsets.tenant_id IN (:tenant_id_1, :tenant_id_2) 
AND recordsets.name IN (:name_1, :name_2)
2015-11-16 15:50:25,137 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'domain_id_1': 'THE actual domain id', 'tenant_id_1': 234, 'tenant_id_2': 456, 'name_1': 'your first name', 'name_2': 'your second example name'}
```

Comment: I am in middle of development phase , I can't be able to go back to engine creation as you specified.What can I do now?

Comment: you're probably calling sqlalchemy.create_engine(...) somewhere in you're code. You could just adjust the parameters. Do you use a logger? Then you could try to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950385/debugging-displaying-sql-command-sent-to-the-db-by-sqlalchemy (Look at the accepted answer.)

Comment: just enable logging using standard python logging module: `logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)` to enable logging any later time in your code after engine has been created. Here I assume that you configured logging at the start of your application already.