# SQLAlchemy - how to print the INSERT, UPDATE, DELTE queries send by db session

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I want to print the SQL statements generated on INSERT, UPDATE, DELTE queries send by sqlalchemy db session. 
I am using sqlalchemy as ORM and sqlite3 database.
I know I can print the SQL of a query using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950385/debugging-displaying-sql-command-sent-to-the-db-by-sqlalchemy).

Like it is shown below

```
INSERT INTO Table (id) VALUES (?)
(1)
```

But I want to print the query and parameter in one line like this

```
INSERT INTO Table (id) VALUES (1);
```

I only want to print the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries.

How can I do this?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/23835766/7853322

Comment: hi @brddawg I tried this. It requires the db_session.query object. But for insert/update queries I am using db_session.add(object_to_be_saved) and for delete queries I am using db_session.delete(object_to_be_saved).
Also when I tried to do db_session.query.statement I was getting error as object has no attribute 'statement'