# sqlalchemy logging doesn't show parameter values

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy

I'm setting up SQLAlchemy logging like so, so that only a specific type of `delete` statements are logged:

```
class DeleteFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return 'DELETE FROM cr_pending_config WHERE cr_pending_config.id' in record.getMessage()

logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addFilter(DeleteFilter())

# create a file handler
handler = logging.FileHandler('sql_log.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.addFilter(DeleteFilter())

# create a logging format
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Problem is, in my log file, I see this:

```
2017-11-07 20:34:44,196 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - DELETE FROM cr_pending_config WHERE cr_pending_config.id = %s
2017-11-07 20:40:37,169 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - DELETE FROM cr_pending_config WHERE cr_pending_config.id = %s
2017-11-07 20:41:21,704 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - DELETE FROM cr_pending_config WHERE cr_pending_config.id = %s
2017-11-07 20:41:21,858 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - DELETE FROM cr_pending_config WHERE cr_pending_config.id = %s
2017-11-07 20:41:21,987 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - DELETE FROM cr_pending_config WHERE cr_pending_config.id = %s
2017-11-07 20:41:44,658 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - DELETE FROM cr_pending_config WHERE cr_pending_config.id = %s
```

That is, the actual IDs are not being logged. Why ???

Comment: SQLA logs the statements and their parameter lists separately, as shortly mentioned in the [engine configuration docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo). So in essence you've filtered the parameters out.

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate on what I need to do to fix this issue please ? Thanks. I'm very new to SQLAlchemy.

Comment: just remove your log filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging (displaying) SQL command sent to the db by SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950385/debugging-displaying-sql-command-sent-to-the-db-by-sqlalchemy)