# How to get sqlalchemy query for a delete statement?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm new to sqlalchemy and have been trying to figure this out for days!

I have some python code which is executing the following line:

`mdb_session.query(PendingConfig).filter(PendingConfig.id == config.id).delete()`

It's deleting all rows in a table called `PendingConfig` which have an `id` equals to a given `config.id`.

**I want to log the underlying SQL query sqlalchemy that generates, but don't know how to do that since `delete()` returns an integer equal to the number of rows deleted.**

I tried setting up a logger but that had it's own issues, as I explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170229/sqlalchemy-logging-doesnt-show-parameter-values).

Need help on this!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get the SQL that was actually run by the MySQL server, then you can enable the MySQL query log or slow query log, and read it from the database server.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html

The MySQL Server doesn't know anything about Python, it just knows that a client sent it a query to execute.

If it's a parameterized query, it will contain `?` placeholders in the SQL text, but SQLAlchemy doesn't do placeholders as far as I know. It always interpolates parameter values into the SQL query before sending it to MySQL.