# PostgreSQL filter performance and query optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-performance

I have some heavy queries where performance requires that filters are applied before joins. According to [some SO posts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133317)

> The query optimizer is often smart enough to filter early.

```
session.query(Table1.post_id)\
    .join(Table2, Table1.post_id == Table2.post_id)\
    .filter(and_(Table1.user_id == thing1.id, Table2.blob_id == thing2.id))
```

Should I expect this type of query to be performed such that filters are applied before the join?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)

Comment: have you tried to debug an [actual query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950385/debugging-displaying-sql-command-sent-to-the-db-by-sqlalchemy)?

Comment: This is more about "Postgresql performance" than "SQLAlchemy filter performance", unless you're asking how to run `EXPLAIN` on SQLA queries.

Comment: The only thing we can analyze is the actual SQL generated by SQLAlchemy that gets passed to Pg to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, PostgreSQL will apply the filters first *whenever it expects that to be faster*, which will probably always be the case.

To be certain, get the actual SQL statement and examine the execution plan with

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...;
```