# Isolating py.test DB sessions in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm trying to build a Flask app with Flask-SQLAlchemy; I use pytest to test the DB.  One of the problems seems to be creating isolated DB sessions between different tests.

I cooked up a minimal, complete example to highlight the problem, note that `test_user_schema1()` and `test_user_schema2()` are the same.

Filename: `test_db.py`

```
from models import User

def test_user_schema1(session):
    person_name = 'Fran Clan'
    uu = User(name=person_name)
    session.add(uu)
    session.commit()

    assert uu.id==1
    assert uu.name==person_name

def test_user_schema2(session):
    person_name = 'Stan Clan'
    uu = User(name=person_name)
    session.add(uu)
    session.commit()

    assert uu.id==1
    assert uu.name==person_name
```

If the db is truly isolated between my tests, both tests should pass.  However, the last test always fails, because I haven't found a way to make db sessions rollback correctly.

[image: sqlalchemy_session_fail]

`conftest.py` uses the following based on what I saw in [Alex Michael's blog post](http://alexmic.net/flask-sqlalchemy-pytest/), but this fixture code breaks because it apparently doesn't isolate the db sessions between fixtures.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def session(app, db):
    connection = db.engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()

    #options = dict(bind=connection, binds={})
    options = dict(bind=connection)
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)

    yield session

    # Finalize test here
    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
    session.remove()
```

For the purposes of this question, I built ***[a gist](https://gist.github.com/mpenning/34fa8d274fc4be240933)***, which contains all you need to reproduce it; you can clone it with `git clone https://gist.github.com/34fa8d274fc4be240933.git`.

I am using the following packages...

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.0.1
Flask-Migrate==1.3.0
Flask-Moment==0.4.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.1
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-WTF==0.11
itsdangerous==0.24
pytest==2.6.4
Werkzeug==0.10.1
```

#### Two questions:

1. Why is status quo broken?  This same py.test fixture seemed to work for someone else.
2. How can I fix this to work correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.

According to [Session Basics - SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_basics.html#committing):

> `commit()` is used to **commit the current transaction.** It always issues flush() beforehand to flush any remaining state to the database; this is independent of the “autoflush” setting. ....

So `transaction.rollback()` in session fixture function does not take effect, because the transaction is already committed.

---

2.

Change scope of fixtures to `function` instead of `session` so that db is cleared every time.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def app(request):
    ...

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def db(app, request):
    ...
```

---

BTW, If you use in-memory sqlite database, you don't need to delete the db files, and it will be faster:

```
DB_URI = 'sqlite://'  # SQLite :memory: database

...

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def db(app, request):
    _db.app = app
    _db.create_all()
    yield _db
    _db.drop_all()
```

Comment: Regarding point number 1: here is my quandry; I want to test that User.id's `primary_key` is written correctly and auto_increments as I expect.  However, I can't really do that unless I `session.commit()`, right?  Apologies if this is a dumb question, I'm a bit new to SQLAlchemy

Comment: @MikePennington, Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Here's the forked version: https://gist.github.com/jeong-min-lee/28fd88babe2808afe9ba (only `conftest.py` is modified) and the test result screenshot:http://i.imgur.com/LxZnsvw.png

Comment: @MikePennington, To be clear, I didn't mean to remove a call to the `session.commit`.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to avoid `scope=function` because I didn't want to deal with the time to re-create the db, but an in-memory DB is pretty fast.  I am developing in sqlite and will probably deploy on postgres or oracle. An in-memory test for other DBs (such as Oracle) probably won't work but this is good enough

Comment: @falsetru about the rollback not taking effect, please also see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites

Comment: Point 1 is incorrect. In the case above, the session is already in a transactional state(`connection.begin()`) when the first call to commit is made. Thanks to the connection's ability to maintain subtransactions, rolling back the outermost transaction rolls back the whole database interaction.

Answer (score 19):

The method introduced in [Alex Michael's blog post](http://alexmic.net/flask-sqlalchemy-pytest/) is not working because it's incomplete. According to the [sqlalchemy documentation on joining sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites), Alex's solution works only if there are no rollback calls. Another difference is, a vanilla `Session` object is used in sqla docs, compared to a scoped session on Alex's blog.

In the case of flask-sqlalchemy, the scoped session is automatically removed on [request teardown](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L836). A call to `session.remove` is made, which issues a rollback under the hood. To support rollbacks within the scope of the tests, use `SAVEPOINT`:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def db_session(db):
    """
    Creates a new database session for a test. Note you must use this fixture
    if your test connects to db.

    Here we not only support commit calls but also rollback calls in tests.
    """
    connection = db.engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()

    options = dict(bind=connection, binds={})
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)

    session.begin_nested()

    # session is actually a scoped_session
    # for the `after_transaction_end` event, we need a session instance to
    # listen for, hence the `session()` call
    @sa.event.listens_for(session(), 'after_transaction_end')
    def restart_savepoint(sess, trans):
        if trans.nested and not trans._parent.nested:
            session.expire_all()
            session.begin_nested()

    db.session = session

    yield session

    session.remove()
    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
```

Your database must support `SAVEPOINT` though.

Comment: For people using sqlite and want to use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36457404/154607

Comment: I've been using a more naive session fixture and dancing around commits in code under test to avoid committing the outer transaction. This answer just vaporized five years of frustration.

Comment: @TravisMehlinger I danced for a year or two before as well. For many times I thought I read the SA docs, but still didn't know how to do things..

Comment: For anyone else puzzled, like I was, there should be a `import sqlalchemy as sa` before this function.

Comment: Thanks a million for this. Lifesaver. In our setup there was one test failing with `sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed`. This was solved by saving the original db.session in a temp var, and restoring it at the end of this function. I'm not sure what happened (it was an auth wrapper trying to access the user DB, so perhaps it ran before / after the test wrapper?)

Comment: by the way there is a typo in the event handler function name ("resetart") but the asinine SO min character edit limit won't let me fix it. @blurrcat if you're still around can you fix it?