# IntegrityError not caught in SQLAlchemy event listener

Tags: python, error-handling, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a simple database driven blog with Flask and SQLAlchemy. In the model for the blog postings I define title and slug attributes:

```
class BlogPost(Model):
    ...
    title = Column(String(80))
    slug = Column(String(80), unique=True)
```

Later I use an event listener to automatically create and insert a slug from the title:

```
@event.listens_for(BlogPost.title, 'set')
def autoslug(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    target.slug = slugify(value)
```

As expected, if I try to add a post to the database, and the title of the post evaluates to the same slug as a previous post, then the transaction fails with an IntegrityError. I don't think in practice this will be a problem anyway. But just for giggles I tried something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

@event.listens_for(BlogPost.title, 'set')
def autoslug(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    try:
        target.slug = slugify(value)
    except IntegrityError:
        target.slug = slugify(value) + random_string()
```

`random_string` could be anything, really, the point is that nothing that I've tried gets executed because the IntegrityError isn't getting caught, and I'm not sure why - attempting to add & commit a post to the database with the same title still raises an IntegrityError and aborts the transaction when I try to commit. I've seen a handful of other posts about it, but the answers are mostly pretty specific to Pyramid, which I'm not using.

Anybody know what I'm missing here?

Tech involved: Python3, Flask, Flask-Sqlalchemy, Sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy will not [flush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#flushing) changes to model objects to DB when setting. In order to get the error you have to do something like

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import object_session

@event.listens_for(BlogPost.title, 'set')
def autoslug(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    session = object_session(target)
    try:
        with session.begin_nested():
            target.slug = slugify(value)
            session.flush()
    except IntegrityError:
        target.slug = slugify(value) + random_string()
```

Note that you have to wrap your possible integrity violation in a nested transaction (a [savepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savepoint)), or your whole transaction will fail even though you catch the `IntegrityError`. If your DB doesn't support savepoints or an SQLAlchemy implementation of the idea, you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm getting "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flush/begin_nested' errors for the inspect and object_session approaches respectively. I think it may have to do with Flask's app contexts and how Flask-Sqlachemy wraps things like the db session. Nevertheless I hadn't heard of either inspect or object_session before, so I think there's some fruitful research for me to do here, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @JohnStill I'm guessing that the `target` (your model object) is not bound to a session and you get `None`. Have you `session.add()`ed it? Though if that is the case, why would the event fire... I'm not quite familiar with the event system in itself, so not 100% sure if ORM events fire even if not bound to a session etc.

Comment: When testing in the shell the 'NoneType' errors are popping up at object creation time, so I never get an object to add to the session. Would I want to do that in the event listener somewhere, like before the try block?

Comment: @JohnStill ah so you're creating the object like `bp = BlogPost(title="my title")` and the event handler will fire during object creation time and there will be no session. You either have to first create the object like `bp = BlogPost()`, `session.add(bp)` and then `bp.title = "mytitle"` or rethink your logic, since automatic slug generation in an event will be infeasible.

Comment: @JohnStill all in all the problem still boils down to the changes not being flushed to the DB and hence no integrity violation happening before a `COMMIT` is attempted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right. As for creating the object first, then adding to the session, then trying to set the attributes, I'm now getting an OperationalError: no such savepoint (from the begin_nested call). At any rate I'm going to tackle this again in the morning, but you've been very helpful, thank you again.

Comment: Might be this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1654857/2681632 , if you're testing with sqlite.